# How to find continuous string or number without spaces?

Tags: mysql

In abc table I have phone number field.

In that field I have records like:

```
123456789
123 456 789
12345 5678
787878787
144444444
```

I want to search only records which not have any space so the query would give result:

```
123456789
787878787
144444444
```

So what should be query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query Where Field DOES NOT Contain $x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232935/sql-query-where-field-does-not-contain-x)

Comment: From your comment below, where you say you also want to remove parentheses, it seems you want to extract all digits from  the field. For example if you have `(123) 456-7890`. If that's the case, you might want to edit your question so that you do all those things in one place rather than solve the problem in small unrelated pieces.

Comment: Given there are already several answers, *maybe* you should ask a *new* question describing properly your actual data format, and the expected output.

Answer (score 7):

MySQL documentation for [LIKE and NOT LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE phone_number NOT LIKE '% %';
```

This will show the output as:

```
phone_number
-----------
123456789
787878787
144444444
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89a88b/1) for above query and table script

Comment: Thanks :) After this result how can i convert all records to (XXX) XXX XXXX to this format

Comment: @AnkitShah you can did it by using phone_number length and concat operations

Comment: UPDATE phone SET CONCAT('(',SUBSTRING( phone FROM 1 FOR LENGTH( phone ) -6 ),')',' ',SUBSTRING( phone FROM 4 FOR LENGTH( phone ) -6 ) ,' ',SUBSTRING( phone FROM 7 FOR LENGTH( phone ) -6 )) WHERE phone
IN (
SELECT phone
FROM test
WHERE phone NOT LIKE '% %'
) why this is not working?

Comment: It's giving error that's why unable to run query in sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 3):

If you only want "digit only" values from an arbitrary string column, you might probably use MySQL regular expression:

```
select * from tbl where col_name REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

---

If you are absolutely sure your columns only contains digits or spaces:

```
select * from abc where col_name not like '% %'
```

Or

```
select * from abc where LOCATE(' ', col_name) = 0
```

---

None of there are *not* index friendly thought...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```