# Get record from mysql excluding the value

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM m2n3r_djcf_items WHERE exp_days=29 AND published=1 AND id>8000 AND email LIKE '%@%'");
```

Need to add next parameter:
In m2n3r_djcf_items we have "promotions" and we can have there
dog,cat,cow or dog,cat or cow etc.

I need to get all records WITHOUT "cat" in "promotions"

Comment: `mysql_query` <- the `mysql_*` extension has been defunct for years...

Comment: @CD001 Yup, deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (over 6 years ago), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `promotions` column is string, and starting from this topic [SQL Query Where Field DOES NOT Contain $x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232935/sql-query-where-field-does-not-contain-x), you can use this SQL query:

```
SELECT email FROM m2n3r_djcf_items WHERE exp_days=29 AND published=1 AND id>8000 AND email LIKE '%@%' AND promotions NOT LIKE '%cat%'
```

But as you can read in that topic, this could slow the query.

Comment: I like how you added a disclaimer about it possibly slowing the query