# Problem with using IN in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can you please help me to understand where is the problem?

```
SELECT mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services FROM mz_t_NaznExec
```

Above script returns recordset where record with p_Services = 200000000000115 not exists

```
SELECT mz_t_Services.p_ID from mz_t_Services
```

Above script returns recordset where record with id = 200000000000115 exists
But this query returns no record

```
SELECT mz_t_Services.p_ID from mz_t_Services where mz_t_Services.p_ID not in(SELECT mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services FROM mz_t_NaznExec)
```

I am using MSSQL
EDIT:
Both p_ID and p_Services data types ara bigint

Comment: What does "SELECT mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services FROM mz_t_NaznExec" return?

Comment: How is your database. Is mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services a foreign key to mz_t_Services.p_ID ?

Comment: ...and who dreamt up those table names?

Comment: SELECT mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services FROM mz_t_NaznExec returns rexordset with a lot of data, where the specified id not exists

Comment: no there are no foreign key in DB

Comment: so what you are saying is, there is no foriegn key and your data needs fixing up...

Comment: Is FK important in this case? I am not master in SQL

Comment: What datatypes are mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services and mz_t_Services.p_ID?

Comment: datatypes are bigint, I edited the post yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are there any NULLs in mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services?  "NOT IN" will always fail if there is even one NULL in the resultset.

Comment: Yess, there are, Thanks a lot RBarry!

Comment: Now I have another good reason why I always use a left (outer) join instead of "in" :)

Comment: There's a good discussion of this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mz_t_Services.p_ID from mz_t_Services where mz_t_Services.p_ID not in(SELECT ISNULL(mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services,0) FROM mz_t_NaznExec)
```

or better

```
SELECT mz_t_Services.p_ID from mz_t_Services where mz_t_Services.p_ID not in(SELECT mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services FROM mz_t_NaznExec WHERE mz_t_NaznExec.p_Services is not null)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jonelf! I fixed up the problem yet

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
SELECT p_id
  FROM mz_t_services
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM mz_t_naznexec
          WHERE mz_t_naznexec.p_services = mz_t_services.p_id
       )
```

I prefer it to the solutions above because it more reliably uses indexes (in my experience).  It works whether there are nulls present or not, so you can just use that form all the time regardless of your expectations of the table contents, and not worry about people asking you why you're checking for nulls in a column that doesn't allow them.

In any case, you should try both solutions and see which works better for you.