# MySQL - How to get a list of values in Table A that don't exist in Table B?

Tags: mysql

```
**Table A**
1
2
3
4
5
6


**Table B**
2
3
5
```

How can I select for entry IDs that only exist in Table B?     In this example, I'm looking for a query that returns 1, 4, and 6.

Comment: what are these values? ids? providing the table structure would actually make this easier on us

Comment: Sorry, yes, they are IDs.  I had originally provided more info but then I thought I'd pare down to only the relevant bits.  Apparently I pared too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the column is named 'id', either:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB WHERE id = a.id)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tableB)
```

You will probably need to test to see which performs best. MySQL can be a bit unpredictable.

Comment: Ah, that's perfect!  Thanks!  Performance isn't an issue here as this this is a one-time query.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select value from B where value not in (select value from A)
```

to get values in B that are not in A.

To get the opposite (values in A not in B) use

```
select value from A where value not in (select value from B)
```

Comment: I'd be very curious to see how this performs against the answer cletus provided. My initial thought was to answer with what he wrote but would't this be faster? Mmm.

Comment: If table B can contain NULL values, NOT IN is a dangerous tool, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values  Consider using NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

This avoids `IN` + subquery:

```
SELECT A.value FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON (A.value = B.value)
WHERE B.value IS NULL
```

Because [`IN (subquery)` isn't optimized](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html) as it is executed for each found row in table A

Comment: That's up to the query optimizer. For example, Sql Server will execute both queries in the same way.

Comment: Yes, but the question being for mysql, it is said in the doc that this query is (still in 6.0 apparently) messed up by the optimizer.