# MySQL: How to find the non exist value in two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - How to get a list of values in Table A that don’t exist in Table B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079585/mysql-how-to-get-a-list-of-values-in-table-a-that-dont-exist-in-table-b)

I have three tables .

**Table x:**

```
+------+
| ID   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
```

**Table Y**

```
+------+
| ID   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
```

**Table Z**

```
+------+
| ID   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
+------+
```

I have to find the value exists in `TABLE Z` but it not exists in table `X and Y` .

Output:

```
+----+
| ID |
------
| 6  |
| 7  |
+----+
```

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS` to make a subquery.

```
SELECT tz.id 
FROM Z tz 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (select 1 from X tx where tx.id = tz.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Y ty where ty.id = tz.id)
```

[@RaphaëlAlthaus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563375/851811) is probably better on efficiency, though. See [Can I get better performance using a JOIN or using EXISTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/227037/851811)

The MySQL reference has a section on `EXISTS`: [13.2.9.6. Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

Comment: Hmmm, not sure about efficency, but I must admit I usually prefer the "EXISTS" syntax for its better readability int these cases ;)

Comment: People. Did I miss the memo? What's wrong with LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Strawberry: You missed it (tagline: readability). I admit it's a matter of personal preference though.

Comment: @Downvoter: Can you please explain in which way is this answer not useful, so it can improved?

Comment: @Strawberry there's indeed nothing wrong with `left join`. As mentioned in the answer and related question, it _might_ be even better regarding efficiency. As for readability, `exists` might be easier for the OP to understand. And in this case it's not necessary to fetch any of the joined tables' data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT z.ID 
FROM TableZ z
LEFT JOIN TableX x on x.ID = z.ID
LEFT JOIN TableY y on y.Id = z.ID
WHERE x.Id IS NULL 
AND y.ID IS NULL
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c38c/7)(with Xavi Lopez and mine, both giving same result)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.ID
FROM    tableZ a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID FROM tableX
            UNION 
            SELECT ID FROM tableY
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c38c/8)

Answer (score 0):

you can use minus function

```
SELECT * FROM Z
MINUS
(
SELECT * FROM Y
UNION
SELECT * FROM X
)
```

Comment: MySQL does not support the (Oracle's) `MINUS` operator. Neither the `EXCEPT` operator.