# SQL "select where not in subquery" returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database where one table "Common" is referenced by several other tables.  I wanted to see what records in the Common table were orphaned (i.e., had no references from any of the other tables).

I ran this query:

```
select *
from Common
where common_id not in (select common_id from Table1)
and common_id not in (select common_id from Table2)
```

I know that there are orphaned records, but no records were returned.  Why not?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/129152/1667619 answers the WHY question pretty well.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

**Update:**

These articles in my blog describe the differences between the methods in more detail:

- [**`NOT IN` vs. `NOT EXISTS` vs. `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`: `SQL Server`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)
- [**`NOT IN` vs. `NOT EXISTS` vs. `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`: `PostgreSQL`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/)
- [**`NOT IN` vs. `NOT EXISTS` vs. `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`: `Oracle`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/)
- [**`NOT IN` vs. `NOT EXISTS` vs. `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`: `MySQL`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

---

There are three ways to do such a query:

- `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`:

  ```
  SELECT  *
  FROM    common
  LEFT JOIN
          table1 t1
  ON      t1.common_id = common.common_id
  WHERE   t1.common_id IS NULL
  ```
- `NOT EXISTS`:

  ```
  SELECT  *
  FROM    common
  WHERE   NOT EXISTS
          (
          SELECT  NULL
          FROM    table1 t1
          WHERE   t1.common_id = common.common_id
          )
  ```
- `NOT IN`:

  ```
  SELECT  *
  FROM    common
  WHERE   common_id NOT IN
          (
          SELECT  common_id
          FROM    table1 t1
          )
  ```

When `table1.common_id` is not nullable, all these queries are semantically the same.

When it is nullable, `NOT IN` is different, since `IN` (and, therefore, `NOT IN`) return `NULL` when a value does not match anything in a list containing a `NULL`.

This may be confusing but may become more obvious if we recall the alternate syntax for this:

```
common_id = ANY
(
SELECT  common_id
FROM    table1 t1
)
```

The result of this condition is a boolean product of all comparisons within the list. Of course, a single `NULL` value yields the `NULL` result which renders the whole result `NULL` too.

We never cannot say definitely that `common_id` is not equal to anything from this list, since at least one of the values is `NULL`.

Suppose we have these data:

```
common

--
1
3

table1

--
NULL
1
2
```

`LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `NOT EXISTS` will return `3`, `NOT IN` will return *nothing* (since it will always evaluate to either `FALSE` or `NULL`).

In `MySQL`, in case on non-nullable column, `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `NOT IN` are a little bit (several percent) more efficient than `NOT EXISTS`. If the column is nullable, `NOT EXISTS` is the most efficient (again, not much).

In `Oracle`, all three queries yield same plans (an `ANTI JOIN`).

In `SQL Server`, `NOT IN` / `NOT EXISTS` are more efficient, since `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` cannot be optimized to an `ANTI JOIN` by its optimizer.

In `PostgreSQL`, `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `NOT EXISTS` are more efficient than `NOT IN`, sine they are optimized to an `Anti Join`, while `NOT IN` uses `hashed subplan` (or even a plain `subplan` if the subquery is too large to hash)

Comment: +1 because, four and a half years on, this answer helped me out with a problem that had me stumped!

Comment: @Carson63000 Snap! I thought I was going mad before I saw this answer

Comment: What does the `NOT EXISTS ` part do in the second solution? What purpose does the `SELECT NULL` part serve ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: `NOT EXISTS` evaluates to TRUE if the query inside it returns any rows. `SELECT NULL` could as well be `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1` or anything else, the `NOT EXISTS` predicate does not look at the rows' values, only counts them.

Comment: In typical cases, the first alternative (the LEFT | RIGHT JOIN / IS NULL), is an exclusive join, and SQL databases are designed to handle this request with very high performance.

Answer (score 51):

If you want the world to be a two-valued boolean place, you must prevent the null (third value) case yourself.

Don't write IN clauses that allow nulls in the list side.  Filter them out!

```
common_id not in
(
  select common_id from Table1
  where common_id is not null
)
```

Comment: nulls in the in-clause-list are a common reason for missing query results.

Comment: ' When comparing with a null, the answer is unknown ' -  from the answer by @Jeremy Stein. From `common_id not in`, we can still have `common_id` value that is `NULL`. So doesn't the problem of  getting no results still persist ?

Answer (score 13):

### The short answer:

There is a NULL within the collection returned by your subquery. You can solve the problem by removing that NULL value before finishing the subquery or to use `NOT EXISTS` predicate instead of `NOT IN`, as it does it implicitly.

### The long answer (From T-SQL Fundamentals, Third edition, by Itzik Ben-Gan)

This is an example: **Imagine there is a order with a NULL orderid inside Sales.Orders table**, so the subquery returns some integers, and a NULL value.

```
SELECT custid, companyname
FROM Sales.Customers
WHERE custid NOT IN(SELECT O.custid
             FROM Sales.Orders AS O);
```

The explanation on why the query from above returns an empty set:

Obviously, the culprit here is the `NULL` customer ID you added to the Orders table. The `NULL` is one of the elements returned by the subquery.
Let’s start with the part that does behave like you expect it to. The IN predicate returns TRUE for a customer who placed orders (for example, customer 85), because such a customer is returned by the subquery. The NOT operator negates the `IN` predicate; hence, the `NOT TRUE` becomes `FALSE`, and the customer is discarded. The expected behavior here is that if a customer ID is known to appear in the Orders table, you know with certainty that you do not want to return it.

However (take a deep breath), if a customer ID from Customers doesn’t appear in the set of non-NULL customer IDs in Orders, and there’s also a `NULL` customer ID in Orders, you can’t tell with certainty that the customer is there—and similarly you can’t tell with certainty that it’s not there. Confused? I hope I can clarify this explanation with an example.

The `IN` predicate returns `UNKNOWN` for a customer such as 22 that does not appear in the set of known customer IDs in Orders. That’s because when you compare it with known customer IDs you get FALSE, and when you compare it with a NULL you get `UNKNOWN`. `FALSE` OR `UNKNOWN` yields `UNKNOWN`. Consider the expression `22 NOT IN (1, 2, <other non-22 values>, NULL)`. This expression can be rephrased as `NOT 22 IN (1, 2, …, NULL)`. You can expand this expression to `NOT (22 = 1 OR 22 = 2 OR … OR 22 = NULL)`. Evaluate each individual expression in the parentheses to its truth value and you get `NOT (FALSE OR FALSE OR … OR UNKNOWN)`, which translates to `NOT UNKNOWN`, which evaluates to `UNKNOWN`.

The logical meaning of `UNKNOWN` here, before you apply the `NOT` operator, is that it can’t be
determined whether the customer ID appears in the set, because the `NULL` could represent that
customer ID. The tricky part here is that negating the `UNKNOWN` with the `NOT` operator still yields
`UNKNOWN`. This means that in a case where it is unknown whether a customer ID appears in a set, it
is also unknown whether it doesn’t appear in the set. Remember that a query filter discards rows that
get `UNKNOWN` in the result of the predicate.

In short, when you use the `NOT IN` predicate against a subquery that returns at least one `NULL`,
the query always returns an empty set. So, what practices can you follow to avoid such trouble? First,
when a column is not supposed to allow `NULLs`, be sure to define it as `NOT NULL`. Second, in all
queries you write, you should consider NULLs and the three-valued logic. Think explicitly about
whether the query might process NULLs, and if so, whether SQL’s treatment of NULLs is correct for
you. When it isn’t, you need to intervene. For example, our query returns an empty set because of the
comparison with the `NULL`. If you want to check whether a customer ID appears only in the set of
known values, you should exclude the NULLs—either explicitly or implicitly. To exclude them explicitly,
add the predicate `O.custid` IS NOT NULL to the subquery, like this:

```
SELECT custid, companyname
FROM Sales.Customers
WHERE custid NOT IN(SELECT O.custid
                    FROM Sales.Orders AS O
                    WHERE O.custid IS NOT NULL);
```

You can also exclude the NULLs implicitly by using the `NOT EXISTS` predicate instead of `NOT IN`,
like this:

```
SELECT custid, companyname
FROM Sales.Customers AS C
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT *
    FROM Sales.Orders AS O
    WHERE O.custid = C.custid);
```

Recall that unlike `IN`, `EXISTS` uses two-valued predicate logic. `EXISTS` always returns `TRUE` or
`FALSE` and never `UNKNOWN`. When the subquery stumbles into a `NULL` in `O.custid`, the expression
evaluates to `UNKNOWN` and the row is filtered out. As far as the `EXISTS` predicate is concerned, the
`NULL` cases are eliminated naturally, as though they weren’t there. So `EXISTS` ends up handling only
known customer IDs. Therefore, it’s safer to use `NOT EXISTS` than `NOT IN`.

*The information above is taken from Chapter 4 - Subqueries, T-SQL Fundamentals, Third edition*

Answer (score 8):

Table1 or Table2 has some null values for common_id.  Use this query instead:

```
select *
from Common
where common_id not in (select common_id from Table1 where common_id is not null)
and common_id not in (select common_id from Table2 where common_id is not null)
```

Comment: What if there's data in one table but not the other? Do you want "and" or "or" there?

Comment: I'm looking for records not referenced in any table, so I want AND.  I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 5):

```
select *
from Common c
where not exists (select t1.commonid from table1 t1 where t1.commonid = c.commonid)
and not exists (select t2.commonid from table2 t2 where t2.commonid = c.commonid)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just off the top of my head...

```
select c.commonID, t1.commonID, t2.commonID
from Common c
     left outer join Table1 t1 on t1.commonID = c.commonID
     left outer join Table2 t2 on t2.commonID = c.commonID
where t1.commonID is null 
     and t2.commonID is null
```

I ran a few tests and here were my results w.r.t. @patmortech's answer and @rexem's comments.

If either Table1 or Table2 is not indexed on commonID, you get a table scan but @patmortech's query is still twice as fast (for a 100K row master table).

If neither are indexed on commonID, you get two table scans and the difference is negligible.

If both are indexed on commonID, the "not exists" query runs in 1/3 the time.

Comment: That should be an AND in the where clause.  Otherwise, that works.

Comment: changed per your comment.  The "or" picks out orphans in either table.

Comment: That's better.  By the way, is there some reason I should use outer joins rather than the subquery?

Comment: Readability is primary one.  I suspect a better execution plan would be generated but without a query plan, I can't confirm.

Comment: This approach is worse that using NOT EXISTS - the join results in fetching more rows than it needs, then the results compared for the columns being null.  And NOT EXISTS is more readable to boot.

Comment: @rexem - you can't make that claim without an execution plan.

Comment: : Think about what the query has to do to produce the results.  It's OK to think for yourself than to hide behind the execution plan defense.  An execution plan is only as good as the data model.

Comment: @rexem -- you've argued a point that should now be an answer.

Comment: @Austin: That doesn't stop hack answers like these from perpetuating themselves.  Don't get me wrong - your answer works, but it's in the realm of putting SELECTs in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @rexem -- point conceded.  But you could add value to the question by posting a well-explained response.

Comment: I tried both ways and, for my data, the subqueries were 5-10% faster.

Comment: @Austin: I've added my comment to that one too.  Sorry if you felt you were being made a target.

Comment: @rexem -- I still would like to see your answer explained on something I could vote and give you credit for.  I used @patmortech's answer and compared with mine and it resulted in nearly identical query plans WRT cost.  Both did table scans of T1 & T2.  My query 51% of the batch; his 49%.

Comment: @Austin: Appreciated, but patmortech's answer was in before I found the question.

Comment: It may have been but it does little to explain why it's better than an alternative.

Comment: for most of the stuff i've done using the joins with the where clause were faster than the sub queries.  *shrugs*.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT T.common_id
  FROM Common T
       LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 ON T.common_id = T1.common_id
       LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T.common_id = T2.common_id
 WHERE T1.common_id IS NULL
   AND T2.common_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This approach is worse that using NOT EXISTS - the join results in fetching more rows than it needs, then the results compared for the columns being null.  It works, but the performance will not be as good - possibly worse that using IN with correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose these values for common_id:

```
Common - 1
Table1 - 2
Table2 - 3, null
```

We want the row in Common to return, because it doesn't exist in any of the other tables.  However, the null throws in a monkey wrench.

With those values, the query is equivalent to:

```
select *
from Common
where 1 not in (2)
and 1 not in (3, null)
```

That is equivalent to:

```
select *
from Common
where not (1=2)
and not (1=3 or 1=null)
```

This is where the problem starts.  When comparing with a null, [the answer is unknown](http://itpov.com/archives/59).  So the query reduces to

```
select *
from Common
where not (false)
and not (false or unkown)
```

false or unknown is unknown:

```
select *
from Common
where true
and not (unknown)
```

true and not unkown is also unkown:

```
select *
from Common
where unknown
```

The where condition does not return records where the result is unkown, so we get no records back.

One way to deal with this is to use the exists operator rather than in.  Exists never returns unkown because it operates on rows rather than columns.  (A row either exists or it doesn't; none of this null ambiguity at the row level!)

```
select *
from Common
where not exists (select common_id from Table1 where common_id = Common.common_id)
and not exists (select common_id from Table2 where common_id = Common.common_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me :)

```
select 
  * 
from 
  Common 
where 
  common_id not in (
    select 
      ISNULL(common_id, 'dummy-data') 
    from 
      Table1
  ) 
  and common_id not in (
    select 
      ISNULL(common_id, 'dummy-data') 
    from 
      Table2
  )
```

Comment: @marlar, the sub-queries always return 1 or 0, not a list of values. So how will the `NOT IN` perform there ?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below example to understand the above
topic:

Also you can visit the following link to know [Anti join](https://www.wowdbase.com/2020/04/anti-join-in-oracle.html)

```
select department_name,department_id from hr.departments dep
where not exists 
    (select 1 from hr.employees emp
    where emp.department_id=dep.department_id
    )
order by dep.department_name;
```

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME DEPARTMENT_ID
Benefits    160
Construction    180
Contracting 190
.......
```

But if we use `NOT IN` in that case we do not get any data.

```
select Department_name,department_id from hr.departments dep 
where department_id not in (select department_id from hr.employees );
```

> no data found

This is happening as (`select department_id from hr.employees`) is returning a null value and the entire query is evaluated as false. We can see it if we change the SQL slightly like below and handle null values with NVL function.

```
select Department_name,department_id from hr.departments dep 
where department_id not in (select NVL(department_id,0) from hr.employees )
```

Now we are getting data:

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME DEPARTMENT_ID
Treasury    120
Corporate Tax   130
Control And Credit  140
Shareholder Services    150
Benefits    160
....
```

Again we are getting data as we have handled the null value with NVL function.

Comment: SQl results are not  appearing in tabular form, please bare with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
(select COUNT(ID)  from ProductMaster where ProductMaster.CatID = CategoryMaster.ID) as coun 
from CategoryMaster
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an example where I was looking up and because one table held the value as a double, the other as a string, they would not match (or not match without a cast). But only **NOT IN**. As **SELECT ... IN ...** worked. Weird, but thought I would share in case anyone else encounters this simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party :)

Your statement:

```
where common_id not in (select common_id from Table1)
and common_id not in (select common_id from Table2)
```

looks for `common_id` not in `Table1` AND not in `Table2`.

What if it's not in Table1 but in Table2 - although it violates your "orphan" definition.