# "Not In" query fails

Tags: mysql

pulling some info from a MySQL db via openquery:

```
select *
from foo
where bar not in (select bar from foobar)
```

Now, if I replace the subquery with hardwired numbers, it works fine, but i have near a 1000 numbers i need to exclude.  I haven't been able to figure this out; both queries run fine by themselves.  the error always tells me I have an syntax error in 'select bar from foobar)'

thanks

Edit:

here is the error:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-4.0.20-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select bar from foobar)' at line 3".
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Can you show the actual query you are using not one replaced with 'foo' and 'foobar'

Comment: Nothing really wrong with that query setup, unless your non-foo/barred fields are reserved words.

Comment: Works just fine: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80d42/1.  What do you mean by "via openquery"?

Comment: openquery is an SQL Server function that lets you link to and query other DBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be one, or more of the following situations:

1. foo is not a table
2. bar is not a column from foo table
3. foobar is not a table
4. bar is not a column from foobar table
5. bar from foo table and bar from foobar have different (not compatible) datatypes

---

It's *possibly* a BUG from MYSQL4.0 (check [HERE](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5367) for that info).

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` like this:

```
select *
from foo
where bar NOT EXISTS (select bar from foobar WHERE foobar.bar = foo.bar)
```

Comment: hmmm....it could be number 5.  I don't have the greatest access to the box, so I don't know how the columns were setup datatype wise.  I will dig into this.

Comment: If it works when you put numbers, bar in foo table must be a number datatype and possibly it's not in bar from foobar table.

Comment: I checked both columns were numbers by attempting math on them, both allowed for propeer math (both interger and float) to be done on them

Comment: From more searching I have been doing, it looks like this is an issue with openquery on the SQL Server side, which I should of guess right off after some basic syntax was erroring.

Comment: @Limey check my edit and try what I've put. Prolly should work as a fix for now.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any NULLs in your foobar subquery? This would mess up your approach. If so, more details at [SQL "select where not in subquery" returns no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406215/sql-select-where-not-in-subquery-returns-no-results)

Comment: no nulls, selecting a primary key, but i double checked, jus to make sure.  :)