# Issue with a SELECT statement within a IN

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I'm trying to select a bunch of rows from my first table depending of values from my second table.

To realize that, I came up with the following query :

```
SELECT *

FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.id IN(

    SELECT subquery.id

    FROM
    (

        SELECT id

        FROM table1 t1
        WHERE (t1.property=10 AND t1.value=0)

    ) AS subquery

    INNER JOIN
    (

        SELECT id

        FROM table1 t1
        WHERE (t1.property=20 AND i.value=1) 

    ) AS subquery2

    on subquery.id=subquery2.id

)
```

Depending of the **property** and **value** from **table1**, a specific list of **id** will be selected to be used as a condition for the final **SELECT** with the **table2**.

The subquery in itself is working, I tested it and I could retrieve the good  **id**.

```
+------+
|  id  |
|------|
|  18  |
|  55  |
¦      ¦
```

Problem is, the **IN** isn't working, at the end of the final **SELECT** I retrieved all the rows from table2 instead of the ones respecting the condition of having the same **id** as the subquery retrieved earlier.

```
+------+------+---
|  id  | name |
|------|------|---
|  1   |  xx  |
|  2   |  yy  |
¦      ¦      ¦
```

So my question is :

- Why is the subquery ignored in my IN statement and is there a way to bypass that problem ?

**EDIT**

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f5a53/2) as requested, but strangely, the code I posted is working here but not for my database.

Comment: cann you please create an http://sqlfiddle.com/ to demonstrate the behavior

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
            subquery.id
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                id
            FROM
                table1 t1
            WHERE
                (t1.property = 10 AND t1.value = 0)) AS subquery
                INNER JOIN
            (SELECT 
                id
            FROM
                table1 t1
            WHERE
                (t1.property = 20 AND i.value = 1)) AS subquery2 ON subquery.id = subquery2.id)Z ON Z.id=t2.id
```

You can try above code.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Tried it, not working, it keeps getting all the rows from table2

Comment: Can you provide O/P for `SELECT 
            subquery.id
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                id
            FROM
                table1 t1
            WHERE
                (t1.property = 10 AND t1.value = 0)) AS subquery
                INNER JOIN
            (SELECT 
                id
            FROM
                table1 t1
            WHERE
                (t1.property = 20 AND i.value = 1)) AS subquery2 ON subquery.id = subquery2.id`

Answer (score 0):

try like the following; if you are having any null values in the columnn you won't get the expected result.

```
common_id not in
(
  select common_id from Table1
  where common_id is not null
)
```

[SQL "select where not in subquery" returns no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406215/sql-select-where-not-in-subquery-returns-no-results)

Comment: Even though I don't have any NULL in the column, I tried it and the result is still the same