# Restricting the records returned to unique with SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using **Microsoft Access** to design a query (which I will eventually extract and use in my **MFC** application. So far I have this:

[image: SQL Design]

The SQL View is:

```
SELECT [Congregation Speaker Talks].talkno, [Congregation Speaker Talks].congregation
FROM [Congregation Speaker Talks]
WHERE ((([Congregation Speaker Talks].congregation)<>'Keynsham'))
ORDER BY [Congregation Speaker Talks].talkno;
```

The results at the moment are:

[image: Snippet of SQL results]

So it is working because no record with a value of **Keynsham** is listed. But as you can see there are multiple speakers from various congregations who give talk number 1. I only want the number to appear once. I tried using `DISTINCT` and it doesn't work.

## Update

This helped a bit:

[SQL "select where not in subquery" returns no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406215/sql-select-where-not-in-subquery-returns-no-results)

I show you what I have done, but I would like to avoid having to actually add a query into the table.

**Step 1**
I created a query and saved it as `KeynshamTalks`:

```
SELECT [Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number]
FROM [Public Talk Titles] INNER JOIN [Congregation Speaker Talks] ON [Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number] = [Congregation Speaker Talks].talkno
WHERE ((([Congregation Speaker Talks].congregation)="Keynsham"))
ORDER BY [Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number], [Congregation Speaker Talks].congregation;
```

This query returns a list of all the congregation speaker talk numbers where the congregation **IS** set to **Keynsham**.

**Step 2**
Next, I created a new query on my **Public Talk Titles** table. This table only has each talk number once. I used the results of `KeynshamTalks` query as a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Public Talk Titles]
WHERE ((([Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number]) Not In (SELECT [Talk Number]
FROM
[KeynshamTalks]
)))
ORDER BY [Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number];
```

This works. The results are exactly what I want to see.  But how can I move that first query directly into the second query so that it is all one query?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Why do you need the congregation name?

Comment: @serakfalcon I don't need it visible. It is just for development. All I need is a unique list of talk numbers where the congregation is not Keynsham.

Comment: Then use distinct and remove the congregation name. It's the congregation name that is causing the numbers to be duplicated with distinct.

Comment: @serakfalcon If I remove the congregation name then I can't filter down the records to just those which do not have Keynsham.

Comment: You can filter on congregation name without including it in the output, give it a try (without SQL change the "Show" box)

Comment: update your question and show us the expected result please   ( for mr a distinct select should work so could be that i don't understand your question)  .

Comment: @scaisEdge See update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I want:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Public Talk Titles]
WHERE ((([Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number]) Not In (
SELECT [Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number]
FROM [Public Talk Titles] INNER JOIN [Congregation Speaker Talks] ON [Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number] = [Congregation Speaker Talks].talkno
WHERE ((([Congregation Speaker Talks].congregation)="Keynsham"))
)))
ORDER BY [Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number];
```

Comment: Only think lacking with this now is to restrict the list further so that the maximum talk number displayed is 194 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your query with `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT ptt.*
FROM [Public Talk Titles] as ptt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [Congregation Speaker Talks] as cst
                  WHERE ptt.[Talk Number] = cst.talkno AND
                        cst.congregation = "Keynsham"
                 )
ORDER BY ptt.[Talk Number];
```

Notice how table aliases (and getting rid of unneeded parentheses) makes the query much easier to write and to read.

If you only want a subset of talks, then add a `WHERE` clause to the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I can see that it is simpler to look at and I confirm that it works in Access. In my own application in then fails. But my other query works. So I will stick with it. But thank you all the same.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle . . . This version should also be much more efficient, particularly with the correct indexes.

Comment: For some reason when I was using yours my own application was not showing a field name to use. Just * and 1. When I use my query I get "Talk Number" listed. I will have to stay with mine but I will up vote yours.