# MS Access sql using NOT IN

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working in MS Access 2013 with these two tables.

```
t1:       t2:
ID        ID   F1   F2
1              a    a
2         1    b    a
3         2    b    a
```

I know it is not the most ideal way to do this, but I wrote this query to pull all IDs that dont exist in another table.

```
Select [ID] from table1 WHERE [ID] NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table2)
```

The query should return 3, but for some reason this table gives me no results. When I change the query to this, it gives me 3 as the result.

```
Select [ID] from table1 WHERE [ID] NOT IN (SELECT [ID] FROM table2 WHERE [ID] IS NOT NULL)
```

I am unsure to why the logic of why the second query works, but the first one returns no results. When I run the nested query (SELECT [ID] FROM table2) it does not return 3 for either query, so both queries should work. Can anyone explain why the first query does not return anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you simply forget using `not in` with subqueries.  Instead, use `not exists`:

```
Select [ID]
from table1 as t1
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 as t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id);
```

As you have learned, `not in` has the wrong semantics (i.e. behavior) when the subquery returns `NULL`.  Instead of trying to make it work, just use `NOT EXISTS`.  An added bonus is that this readily extends to multiple columns and should use an index if available.

Comment: the NOT EXISTS does not seem to work. it does not return anything when I switch to NOT EXISTS

Comment: @J.Doe Also remember for `Exists` the important part is `t2.id = t1.id`. It doesn't matter what the `Select` says. Often times people will write `Select *` because it isn't even evaluated.

Comment: @Brad . . . In fact, I usually use `select 1` because it is easy to type.

Comment: ahh was missing the t2.id = t1.id part. so this makes the second SELECT query return a single id if it exists, as opposed to a whole list of existing IDs. how come NOT EXISTS does not work with the whole list?

Comment: @J.Doe . . . Because the uncorrelated query returns at least one row.

Comment: oh right cause the WHERE is no longer using ID. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Null` values cannot be evaluated therefore when the query is trying to see if `3` is `=` to `null` it doesn't know how to check that so it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how In works (and Not In, of course) spelled out in detail in the answer to this question:  [SQL "select where not in subquery" returns no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406215/sql-select-where-not-in-subquery-returns-no-results)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using NOT IN, use this (assuming ID can't be negative in table2):

```
Select ID
from table1 
WHERE ID
NOT IN 
(
SELECT Nz(ID,-1) 
FROM table2
)
```

Nz converts a Null value to the provided parameter. If no parameter is provided, Nz converts to zero or a zero-length string.