# mysql NULL value in where in CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, null, where-clause

how to deal with **NULL** value in mysql **where in** CLAUSE

i try like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field IN(1,2,3,NULL)
```

it not working

only work like :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field IN(1,2,3) OR field IS NULL
```

how can i get it work in `WHERE IN` ?  it is possible ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As by my understanding you want to pull every record with 1,2,3 and null value.

I don't think its possible to put null in the IN operator. Its expects values and null is well.. not a value. So You really have to put the OR with the null to get the desired result.

Answer (score 15):

There is a MySQL function called [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). It returns the first non-`NULL` value in the list, or `NULL` if there are no non-`NULL` values.

If you for example run `SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, -1);` you will get `-1` back because it's the first non-`NULL` value.

So the trick here is to wrap your expression in `COALESCE`, and add a value as the last parameter that you also add in your `IN` function.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE COALESCE(field,-1) IN (1,2,3,-1)
```

It will only match if field is 1,2 or 3, or if field is `NULL`.

Comment: Nice trick but isn't it worth to note that the arbitrary value (here `-1`) becomes forbidden for `field` ? Or the SELECT will also return lines presenting this value for `field`

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this information from the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) helps:

> To comply with the SQL standard, IN  returns NULL not only if the expression on the left hand side is NULL, but also if no match is found in the list and **one of the expressions in the list is NULL**.

Answer (score 0):

Using UNION as a subquery in IN operator can get tableIds as a list and from that can get results with the NULL value.

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM
mytable 
WHERE mytable.id IN(
    SELECT mytable.id
    FROM mytable
    where mytable.field IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT mytable.id 
    FROM mytable
    WHERE mytable.field IN(1,2,3)
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Following statement should help:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE COALESCE(field,0) IN (1,2,3,0)
```

Comment: What makes you think that simply dumping a query helps? **How** does that query answer the given problem?