# Find rows in one table that are not in another - SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

Please tell me why this does not work:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
where t1.id not in
(select t2.id
from table2 t2
where t2.somedate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
)
group by t1.id
```

The subquery works and the first select works but when I run the whole thing it comes up blank.

I am trying to find records (IDs) in one table that are not in another.

Any help would be much appreciated.
This is on SQL Server btw.

Thanks

Comment: I have had the same problem using "not in". It's either a bug in sqlserver, or something about it that I don't understand. Use a left join as proposed. Maybe "not exists" works, don't quite remember. If anyone has any inputs as to why "not in" doesn't work, I would love to hear it..

Comment: Is your subquery returning any `NULL`s?

Comment: This is due to NULL id in table, you can use Not Exists/Left Join(see my answer below)/Convert Null to something like "-1".

Comment: [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: Thank you all...all makes sense now :)

Comment: another good-to-read..: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the left join

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
Left Join table2 t2 on T2.Id=t1.id and
t2.somedate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
where t2.id is null  group by t1.id
```

Other option is to use exists

```
select
    t1.id
from
    table1 t1
where
    not exists
    (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and 
     t2.somedate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
    and t2.id is null  group by t1.id)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. Both of these work and give the same results. Btw, after the dates in the second query you have 'where' - this should be 'and' :)

Comment: @Imm:- Upadated that!

Answer (score 0):

Use Left join

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
Left Join table2 t2 on T2.Id=t1.id and
t2.somedate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
where t2.id is null
group by t1.0
```

Or your query updated

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
where isnull(t1.id,-1) not in
(select isnull(t2.id,-1)
from table2 t2
where t2.somedate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
)
group by t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table2 may contains `NULL` result of id, so `NOT IN` not performed as expected.

Reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3925698/1287352