# more efficient way of using sql OR?

Tags: sql

i am wondering if their is a better way of doing something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE colour='red' OR colour='greed' OR colour='blue' OR colour='yellow'
```

is their anything like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE colour='red''greed''yellow'
```

cheers in advance

Comment: Just exactly what color is "greed"? The artist in me wants to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [SQL IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE colour in ('red','greed','yellow');
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Textbook example of a situation IN was designed for.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the IN operator will not handle a NULL case the way some people might expect:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE color = 'blue' OR color IS NULL
```

is not the same as:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE color IN ('blue', NULL)
```

While this may seem obvious to look for in code, it can be pernicious when the IN is a sub-select, and NULLs are in the inner results:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE color IN (SELECT color FROM tbl2)
```

And it exhibits [possibly even more unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values) in the NOT IN case

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` Operator should be able to do what you need it to.

see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Basically you could say

`SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE colour IN ('red','green','yellow')`