# NOT IN Returns Unexpected Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running the following queries in MS SQL Server (version 2016 if that matters).

```
SELECT DISTINCT Job_Number
FROM table_A
WHERE Job_Number IS NOT NULL
```

returns 2376 rows

```
SELECT *
FROM table_A
WHERE Job_Number IN (SELECT DISTINCT [House Bill] FROM table_B)
```

returns 137 rows

However,

```
SELECT *
FROM table_A
WHERE Job_Number NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [House Bill] FROM table_B)`
```

returns 0 rows. I would expect this would return 2239 rows (i.e. 2376 - 137).

Is there any fundamental concept of NOT IN that I have yet to understand here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`NOT IN`** will fail to return results if there are any **`NULL`** values returned by your following query: `(SELECT DISTINCT [House Bill] FROM table_B)`

My suggestion is to modify your query to:

`(SELECT DISTINCT [House Bill] FROM table_B WHERE [House Bill] IS NOT NULL)`

The reason this happens is because whenever a comparison is made between a row in `table_A` with `NULL` value in `table_B` the logical result is `UNKNOWN`.

There's more information about this:

[1 - here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values)
and

[2 - here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748620/sql-server-not-in)

Answer (score 0):

The `IN()` clause ignores `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason would be `null` values in `tableb` in `[House Bill]` column :

The correct way would be to use `NOT EXISTS` OR `EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`  AND `IN` clause :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_B b WHERE a.Job_Number = b.[House Bill]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` returns no rows at all if the subquery returns `NULL` -- even once.

For that reason, I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS`.  This behaves as you expect:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 NFROM table_B b WHERE a.Job_Number = b.[House Bill])
```