# IN clause, NULL handling in TSQL/SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, exists

Suppose there is a table like this:

```
f1      f2
----------
1       3
4       8
6       4
NULL    1
```

The following query works as expected :

```
SELECT f2
  FROM Table_1 a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM Table_1 
                    WHERE a.f2 = f1)
```

...and result set is:

```
f2
---
3
8
```

...but similar query with `IN` returns nothing:

```
SELECT f2
  FROM Table_1 a
 WHERE f2 NOT IN (SELECT b.f1 
                    FROM Table_1 b)
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: The inner-most SELECT goes against `Table_1` in your first query, and against `tbltemp b` in your second query - just a typo??

Comment: Yes marc_s 
Sorry . I made a mistake

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because of the `null` value in f1. Try this instead.

```
SELECT      f2
FROM         Table_1 a
WHERE f2 NOT IN (select b.f1 
                 from Table_1 b
                 where b.f1 is not null)
```

Here is a great explanation as to why it is so. [NOT IN clause and NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values/129152#129152)

Comment: Similar question from a few years ago.  Common problem with tri-state logic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values

Comment: [A more detailed explanation by Joe Celko here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/)

Comment: by the way as my fault , "tbltemp" was typo.  
It should be replaced with "Table_1"