# SQL Server 2008 not in null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

I had a strange error where I did something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NAME COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS NOT IN (select name FROM table2)
```

`Name` was a `nvarchar(50)` `null`. `Table2` had `null` values in the `name` column. It would then match names that did not exist in `table2` because of the `null` values. Meaning that this would return `0` results. And if I did:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NAME COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS NOT IN (
  select name FROM table2 where name is not null
)
```

I would get some results.

One table had collation `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` and the other one `latin1`. Maybe the `COLLATE` is the source of the problem?

Can anyone explain why this happens? Maybe something with set theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with collation. Try `set ansi_nulls off` and the first query will work as you expected.

The reason is that when you try to compare something to NULL (e.g. a = NULL or a <> NULL) the result is UNKNOWN and the entire query fails. If you set `ansi_nulls` to `off` then the same comparison evaluates to TRUE or FALSE and the query "works".

In other words:

```
WHEN a NOT IN (1, 2, null)
```

means

```
WHEN a <> 1 AND a <> 2 AND a <> null
```

WHERE the last part `a <> null` evaluates to UNKNOWN and the query fails to return any rows.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` does not work as some folks would expect when used in a `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` expression.

Basically, SQL Server can't say for sure that something isn't in a subset if the subset contains `NULL` since `NULL` is a state of having an unknown value.

I don't think collation even enters into it, the queries are different.

[See a full explanation of `NULL` in `NOT IN` here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values)

Answer (score 1):

I think I would work around the issue by using

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM table2 t2
                     WHERE (t1.NAME COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS = t2.name)
                        OR (t1.NAME IS NULL AND t2.name IS NULL))
```

No fancy theory though, just practical experience =P