# MySQL "NOT IN" query not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, subtraction

I have a table with three columns: `taxon_id`, `scientific_name_element_id`, and `parent_id`. I want to find the elements that are children and not parents, so the termini of the structure.

I found some sources that suggested that I use

```
select taxon_id 
       from  taxon_name_element
       where taxon_id not in 
                          (select parent_id from taxon_name_element)
```

But this does not work, I get an empty set when I can actually browse the entries and see that there is, for example, a `taxon_id=1`, and NO `parent_id=1`

Conversely when I see what taxon_id's are in parent_id's I get a nonempty result set

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL NOT IN constraint and NULL values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values)

Comment: thanks ruakh, I added an is not null requirement and it worked. Am I understanding this correctly?: if taxon_id is compared to NULL, it returns unknown and unknown added to any number will yield unknown so the result is no rows? Thanks for the linkk

Comment: Yes, exactly. Something like `3 <> NULL` is indeterminate, because the `NULL` might be a three; so, too, is `3 NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)`. MySQL will only return rows that are *known* to satisfy the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are there any NULLs in `taxon_name_element.parent_id`?

The query...

```
select taxon_id 
from taxon_name_element
where taxon_id not in (
    select parent_id
    from taxon_name_element
)
```

...is equivalent to...

```
select taxon_id 
from taxon_name_element
where
    taxon_id <> parent_id_1
    AND taxon_id <> parent_id_2
    ...
    AND taxon_id <> parent_id_N
```

...where `parent_id_X` are actual values that are currently in the `parent_id` column. If even one of them is NULL, the corresponding `taxon_id <> parent_id_X` expressions will "collapse" into NULL, dragging the whole WHERE expression with it.

Filter-out NULLs to get what you want:

```
select taxon_id 
from taxon_name_element
where taxon_id not in (
    select parent_id
    from taxon_name_element
    where parent_id is not null
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the **parent_id** column is **NULL** (meaning no value is set)

To select all **scientific_name_element_id** that have no value for **parent_id** (meaning parent_id is NULL)

You do this:

```
SELECT scientific_name_element_id
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

This will get you a list of scientific_name_element_id that have no parents.

Comment: I think you must have misunderstood the question. Your query will find records that have no *parent*. The OP wants to find records that have no *children*. (By the way, the name of the table is `taxon_name_element`.)