# SQL INSERT INTO if record does not exist (not from a second table)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Through Python, I'm pulling data from a JSON request and inserting into a database, but I want to make sure those records do not already exist before inserting it in there.

I know similar questions have been asked before, but mine is different because mine is not querying from a second table. So how do I approach this?

What I've tried, and I get an incorrect Syntax error, is

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (val1, val2, val3) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select col1 FROM table WHERE col1 != val1)
```

Can anyone give me a better way to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Using Merge procedure is a good solution to this

Comment: Merge for only one row seems too much. I always used @tab-alleman solution (see below) for one insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ...)
  INSERT ... VALUES ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work using this (in case anyone else runs into this problem and needs further clarification) 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col1 = val1) INSERT INTO col1, col2, col3 VALUES val1, val2, val3

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT val1, val2, val3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM table WHERE col1 = val1)
```

Note how SELECT is *not* selecting from a table. It simply returns one row (val1, val2, val3) if the condition holds and zero rows if it doesn't.

---

BTW, you can write that more succinctly as...

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT val1, val2, val3
WHERE val1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM table)
```

...but beware that in the presence of NULLs, this is [not the exact equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344100/533120).

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a Syntax error when I try this. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Emac Whoops, I used `==` (as usual for C-like languages) instead of `=` (as required by SQL).