# finding opposite result using mysql IN

Tags: mysql, subset

I have two mysql tables, event_template and event_occurrence, where event_occurrence has a column with event_template id's. I want to find all event_templates which have no event_occurrence.

Trying this query I get 0 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `event_template` where id NOT IN (SELECT event_template_id FROM event_occurrence)
```

Note that event_template has 166 rows, and 162 are returned by this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `event_template` WHERE id IN (SELECT event_template_id FROM event_occurrence)
```

Comment: I think you might be dealing with a `null` problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/129077; although that question is SQL Server specific, the `IN` and `NOT IN` clauses aren't.

Comment: @JohnConde ok, I didn't know how to do that before, thanks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, ok seems quite knotty then, don't know if it's worth going into for me right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`. This should work for you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM event_template et
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM event_occurrence eo where eo.event_template_id = et.id)
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM event_template WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM event_occurrence where event_template_id = event_template.id)" (a slight change) works perfectly!

Comment: In that case I'm guessing you also have a column named ID in the event_occurence table. I'll update the query above to one that should work for that case.