# WHERE IN works, but not WHERE NOT IN

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

In a `fetchAll()` I'm trying to filter out some options I don't want to fetch. But using `NOT IN` does give a empty array. While using only `IN` with the same parameters it's working:

```
$model->fetchbysql("shortcut NOT IN (2, 3)", null, null);  // Not working
$model->fetchbysql("shortcut IN (2, 3)", null, null);      // Working
```

Comment: May be this answer will help u <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values>

Comment: Your question suggests that the only actual values of the `shortcut` column are `2`, `3` and `NULL`. As most queries involving `NULL` result in `NULL` or `UNKNOWN` depending on the rdbs used, and as neither of these is considered true, those `NULL` rows will be selected by neither query.

Comment: @Nicklas Not working as in *returns no rows*? Does it return an error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your queries like this.

```
SELECT * FROM usermaster WHERE UserId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM usermaster WHERE UserId NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Both SQL queries will work fine.