# sub query not returning expected results

Tags: t-sql, subquery

Baffling query results or lack of...

I am trying to return a record set by excluding records from the set that may already exist in a second table.

```
SELECT        trID
FROM            ttTrct
WHERE        (trID NOT IN
             (SELECT rteVehID
              FROM  rtHist
              WHERE  (rteSchedDT = '11/19/2012 12:00:00 AM')))


ORDER BY tractorID
```

actual where clause is...

```
WHERE  (rteSchedDT = CAST(@targetDate AS DATETIME))
```

But have been also trying with static date value to avoid any issues there.

Three records exist in rtHist

```
 rteVehID    rteSchedDT
 NULL        11/12/2012 12:00:00 AM
 NULL        11/19/2012 12:00:00 AM
 1645        11/19/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Five records exist in ttTrct

```
 trID
 1234
 4567
 9874
 1645
 2442
```

I am expecting my result set to include 4 records and not 1645. But I only get NULL. Also, If the third record in the rtHist table were also NULL instead of 1645, I also get no results. Of course the static date will eventually be a variable.

Any ideas on what I am missing? thanks in advance.  SSEE 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT trID
FROM  ttTrct t
WHERE not exists (SELECT rteVehID
                   FROM  rtHist h
                   WHERE  rteSchedDT = '11/19/2012 12:00:00 AM'
                     and t.trID = h.rteVehID)
ORDER BY tractorID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fafd/4)

Here is a great article about the differences between `NOT IN` and `EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN`:

[NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: Absolutely Awsome!!! Thank you!!!!  For some reason I can not mark this as answer. I will try again shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar situations where nulls slip in to the subquery and mess things up. Try

```
...
WHERE  (rteSchedDT = '11/19/2012 12:00:00 AM'
        and rteScheDT is not null)))
...
```

I suspect this isn't the problem here, but it's worth a shot.

also, why

```
(rteSchedDT = CAST(@targetDate AS DATETIME))
```

? Just make @targetDate a datetime variable.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that the `NOT IN` clause expands to a series of `AND` statements.  Since comparing any value to `NULL` is `NULL` and `AND NULL` always results in `NULL`, your where clause is never `TRUE`.  It's always `NULL`.

Try:

```
SELECT   trID
FROM     ttTrct
WHERE    (trID NOT IN
         (SELECT rteVehID
         FROM  rtHist
         WHERE  (rteSchedDT = '11/19/2012 12:00:00 AM')
             AND rteVehID IS NOT NULL))
```

Alternately you could just use a join, which will very likely have an identical or superior execution plan:

```
SELECT     t.trID
FROM       ttTrct t
INNER JOIN rtHist r
        ON t.trID = r.rtHist
WHERE      r.rteSchedDT = '11/19/2012 12:00:00 AM'
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/sql-not-in-constraint-and-null-values)