# MySQL NOT IN doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query:

```
select e.* 
from emails as e 
where e.error <> 1 
AND e.login NOT IN ( select email_login from accounts )
```

But it returns 0 rows.

```
select e.* 
from emails as e 
where e.error <> 1 
AND e.id NOT IN (select email_id from accounts )
```

Does work correctly.

email_login is `varchar(255)` and id is `int(11)`.

Comment: You absolutely sure? what if you rewrite statement using `not exists` ?

Comment: You should take a look at the `LEFT JOIN` operator

Comment: A fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/ would also help a lot

Comment: well, maybe case-sensitivity leads to your problem, try `...UPPER(e.login) NOT IN ( SELECT UPPER(email_login) FROM accounts WHERE email_login IS NOT NULL )`

Comment: @KevinBrydon it is not of much help for `NOT IN` though

Comment: If it works after you add `where email_login is not null` to subquery, you are a victim of [not in null comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-constraint-and-null-values).

Comment: @vittore what about left joining on the accounts table and selecting based on `accounts.email_id IS NULL`? or maybe I've misread?

Comment: @Najzero: Thank you very much WHERE email_login IS NOT NULL is the solution :)

Comment: @Najzero: post your comment as an answer, please.

Comment: @KevinBrydon nope, you right, I misread.

Comment: @MichałK. as requested I posted an answer, but I Strawberry's solution is also working like a charm and (explain plan) should do plainly spoken: the same as the subquery in most cases

Comment: @Najzero: I know that it's work but I don't want use join's. As Strawberry said is a "religious objection" :) sorry... On the other hand your solution i closer to answer on my question but Strawberry's solution is a new query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer.

My brain said "case sensitive", my fingers added `IS NOT NULL` to the subquery automaticly. My smart fingers bypass NOT NULL problems in comparism :-).

Here is your working query:

```
SELECT e.* from emails AS e 
WHERE e.error <> 1 
AND UPPER(e.login) NOT IN 
(SELECTUPPER(email_login) FROM accounts WHERE email_login IS NOT NULL)
```

my fingers added the UPPER() to that string comparism this time too.

Comment: UPPERCASE is not necessary. In my case there is no option to be different data :) (email logins).

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT e.* 
     FROM emails e 
     LEFT
     JOIN accounts a
       ON a.email_login = e.login
    WHERE e.error <> 1
      AND a.email_login IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you but the solution is WHERE email_login IS NOT NULL I don't want to use joins

Comment: Is that a moral or an emotional objection?

Comment: I am not sure but I think joins are very slow.

Comment: Ah, I see - a religious objection - based upon your beliefs. Well, fair enough ;-)

Comment: I heard while loops are slow too.  After all they run the same block of code again and again!  What's up with that?  I'm not going to use loops anymore. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, down with loops and joins!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `NOT EXISTS` instead of NOT IN

like that:

```
select e.* 
from emails as e 
where e.error <> 1 
AND e.login NOT EXISTS (select email_login from accounts )
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess either e.login or email_login has a `CHAR` type instead of `VARCHAR`. Hence that field is padded with blanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because e.login is NULL, when comparing NULL valuse as in your case as NOT IN it allways returns false (See [documentation: operator NOT LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_not-like) which applies to NOT IN too).

You can check this by using [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) which:

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.

So in your case:

```
 SELECT e.* 
 FROM emails AS e 
 WHERE e.error <> 1 
 AND COALESCE(e.login,'') NOT IN (select email_login from accounts)
```

If this does not work try depending on how exact should be compared either the LIKE operator or the trimmed values to avoid differences because of leading or trailing spaces

**With %LIKE%**:

```
 SELECT e.* 
 FROM emails AS e 
 WHERE e.error <> 1 
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT email_login 
                 FROM accounts 
                 WHERE email_login LIKE CONCAT('%', e.login ,'%'))
```

*Notice that the % matches any number of characters, including zero characters*

**To match the exact login**:

```
 SELECT e.* 
 FROM emails AS e 
 WHERE e.error <> 1 
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT email_login 
                 FROM accounts 
                 WHERE UPPER(TRIM(email_login)) = UPPER(TRIM(e.login)))
```

Comment: -1 You can't put identifiers inside a string literal like that.  Why give an answer of "try this" when you obviously haven't tried it?

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you, fixed. And by the way it is ok to provide an idea answer even if the i did not try it.

Comment: Ok, I reversed my downvote since you have corrected the answer.  I don't agree that it's okay to post answers that are pure guesses, and grossly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM emails e 
WHERE e.error <> 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT * FROM accounts a
 WHERE a.email_login = e.login
 )
;
```