# NOT IN with Nulls - unclear behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, notin

The following query returns NO data:

```
select * from ediImport 
WHERE glnfact NOT IN (select GLN from Clients)
```

After some search, I found the data I want, this way:

```
select * from ediImport 
WHERE glnfact NOT IN (select GLN from Clients WHERE gln is not null)
```

But I feel like the first query SHOULD return the information (and I think it WOULD return it in Access).
So my questions:
 - **why** is first query not working
 - is there a better, more efficient way to do this ? I found EXISTS and ANY but I can't see any advantage over the *old school* way.

---

Note: I don't want to use a left join here since my REAL need is to perform an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE ediImport SET Status = 2 
WHERE glnfact NOT IN (select GLN from Clients WHERE gln is not null)
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-constraint-and-null-values

Comment: @AndreyGordeev: looks right. Since you where first on this, make it a reply, please, so I can mark it as the answer ?

Comment: @iDevlop - Better to close it as a duplicate??

Comment: @iDevlop Since this question is a duplicate there is no need in reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query returns no data because of comparing [null values](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
When you compare 2 values result could be

- `TRUE` if they equals
- `FALSE` if they're not
- `UNKNOWN` if one or two of the values is null

So when you use `not in` sql should compare your value `glnfact` with all values of `GLN` in the subquery and if all compares return `FALSE`, then it returns `TRUE` for the whole `not in` clause. If one of the value of `GLN` is null, comparing it with `glnfact` returns `UNKNOWN` so `not in` clause is `UNKNOWN`.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Answering because of your edit</sup>

If you want to update `Status = 2` in the table `ediImport` which is `NULL` in the table `Clients`, you CAN use `LEFT JOIN` in `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE ei SET ei.Status = 2
  FROM ediImport as ei
  LEFT JOIN Clients c
    ON ei.glnfact = c.gln
 WHERE c.gln IS NULL;
```

#### See [this sample SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61f1e/1)

This is equivalent to `UPDATE` using `NOT IN`. See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bcc01/1)

Comment: While not my main question, this is just perfect for my needs and probably the most efficient solution. Thanks.