# MySQL “WHERE IN” produces proper result but “WHERE NOT IN” does not

Tags: mysql, debugging

This is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `student_classlists` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SessionCode` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CourseCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SectionCode` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StudentId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `FinalGradeSIS` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Faculty` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClassListDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=576 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `Status` column is largely composed of `NULL` rows, with just a few exceptions. I am trying to ignore those records that are not null. The following query does not work:

```
SELECT StudentId FROM student_classlists WHERE `Status` NOT IN ('Drop') GROUP BY StudentId
```

For some reason it produces an unexpected and empty result. But a very similar query with the only exception of dropping the `NOT` produces an expected result

```
SELECT StudentId FROM student_classlists WHERE `Status` IN ('Drop') GROUP BY StudentId
```

What's happening here?

Comment: It would be useful to see some of the data

Comment: Another victim of three-valued logic. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-constraint-and-null-values for the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows with `NULL` status will not appear in the output, because they are neither inside nor outside the `IN` list. To get these rows, add `COALESCE`, like this:

```
SELECT StudentId
FROM student_classlists
WHERE COALESCE(`Status` NOT IN ('Drop'), 1)
GROUP BY StudentId
```

This effectively says that records with `NULL` value in the `Status` column must be included.

Comment: Great - I had the feeling there was something crucial I did not know about MySQL... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only `NULL` `Status` records, you could do:

```
SELECT StudentId FROM student_classlists WHERE Status IS NULL
```