# NOT IN returns false if a value in the list is null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, null

**CUSTOMERS TABLE**

```
CUSTOMER_ID FIRST_NAME     LAST_NAME         DOB        PHONE

1           John            Brown         1/1/1965  800-555-1211
2           Cynthia         Orange        2/5/1968  800-555-1212
3           Steve           White         3/16/1971 800-555-1213
4           Gail            Black                   800-555-1214
5           Doreen          Blue          5/20/1970 
6           Fred            Brown         1/1/1970  800-555-1215
```

If a run a query

```
select * from customers where customer_id not in (2,3,5,NULL);
```

I get an output no rows returned.....Please help me to sort this problem out..

Comment: Please EXPLAIN?????? what does that mean ???

Comment: I mean to say why the output is no rows returned.

Comment: this is not the way to ask question buddy....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got bitten by SQL 3-valued logic.

For the rows with a `customer_id` of 2, 3, or 5, the `WHERE` clause evaluates to false, as you expected.

For the other rows, it evaluates to `UNKNOWN` (or `NULL`; I don't know if Oracle distinguishes them), **not** to true.

This may be more clear if the `IN` expression were expanded to `(customer_id != 2) AND (customer_id != 3) AND (customer_id != 5) AND (customer_id != NULL)`.  For a `customer_id` of 1, 4, or 6, the first three subexpressions evaluated to true, as you'd expected.  But the last one evaluates to unknown, because the `NULL` (a marker for an unknown value) *might* "really" be 1, 4, or 6.  Thus, the entire expression has an unknown truth value.  The `SELECT` statement will only return rows for which the `WHERE` clause is definitely true, not unknown.

You can get the results you wanted by making the query.

```
select * from customers where customer_id not in (2, 3, 5) and customer_id is not null;
```

However, it seems that your `customer_id` is an autoincrement column and can't really be null anyway.  If so, just write:

```
select * from customers where customer_id not in (2, 3, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular instance, you are looking for

```
select * from customers where customer_id not in (2,3,5);
```

The null would be omitted in this case.

Why?

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-constraint-and-null-values), A Not In statment does, in this case the following:

```
select * where CustomerID <> 2 and CustomerID <> 3 and CustomerID <> 5 and CustomerID <> NULL
```

Using the default ansi_nulls notation on, customerID <> NULL would result in an UNKNOWN. When SQL has an UNKNOWN, it will return no rows. When this is off, it would return true.

You have two options at this point:

1. Change the statement to not have a null in it
2. Change your Database Engine to have ansi_nulls off

I think 1 would be the much easier choice in this case...

Comment: But I got an ouput when I executed this query select * from customers where customer_id  in (2,3,5,NULL)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from customers where customer_id not in (2,3,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
select * from customers where customer_id in (2,3,5,NULL)
```

is equal to

```
    select * where CustomerID = 2 or CustomerID = 3 or CustomerID = 5 or CustomerID = NULL
```

The last expression "CustomerID = NULL" returns **always** FALSE, but due to OR condition this does influence the result.

You have to write it like this:

```
select * from customers where customer_id in (2,3,5) or customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: `CustomerId = NULL` always returns null/unknown, NOT false.