# Remove unnecessary rows from a relational table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relational database (mysql) with two tables: Cities and Events .

Cities table:

```
   - city_id
   - city_name
   - city_coord
```

Events table

```
   - event_id
   - event_name
   - event_descr
   - city_id
```

In the Cities table I have 1500+ rows, and nearly 1300 rows aren't linked to the events table. How can I delete these rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
DELETE FROM cities
WHERE city_id NOT IN (SELECT city_id FROM events)
```

As mentioned in the comments, if city_id can be null in events, this will not work.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/129152/1385896) on why that is

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Cities
WHERE city_id NOT IN (SELECT city_id 
                       FROM Events)
```