# Return row only if value doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables - `reservation`:

```
   id  | some_other_column
   ----+------------------
   1   | value
   2   | value
   3   | value
```

And second table - `reservation_log`:

```
   id  | reservation_id | change_type
   ----+----------------+-------------
   1   | 1              | create
   2   | 2              | create
   3   | 3              | create
   4   | 1              | cancel
   5   | 2              | cancel
```

I need to select only reservations NOT cancelled (it is only ID 3 in this example).
I can easily select cancelled with a simple `WHERE change_type = cancel` condition, but I'm struggling with NOT cancelled, since the simple `WHERE` doesn't work here.

Comment: refer to the not equal documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: Those comments are not right, since 1 and 2 have type != cancel.

Comment: if I use not equal condition `WHERE change_type != 'cancel'` it prints all reservations and it is wrong because only reservation with id 3 is not cancelled

Comment: alway be careful of using **NOT IN ()** if the data you are comparing can be NULL e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/129152/2067753

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM reservation
WHERE id NOT IN (select reservation_id
                 FROM reservation_log
                 WHERE change_type = 'cancel')
```

OR:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM reservation r
LEFT JOIN reservation_log l ON r.id = l.reservation_id AND l.change_type = 'cancel'
WHERE l.id IS NULL
```

The first version is more intuitive, but I think the second version usually gets better performance (assuming you have indexes on the columns used in the join).

The second version works because `LEFT JOIN` returns a row for all rows in the first table. When the `ON` condition succeeds, those rows will include the columns from the second table, just like `INNER JOIN`. When the condition fails, the returned row will contain `NULL` for all the columns in the second table. The `WHERE l.id IS NULL` test then matches those rows, so it finds all the rows that don't have a match between the tables.

Comment: @Barmar Well since you seemingly want me asking for help on this question instead of my own.... how do I do this when calling multiple columns from the subquery keeping in mind that an inner join needs a matching column, which will always drop the results that don't match, something that will not work in my situation because I need two columns both which contain usernames.

Comment: @Bruce You can use `ON t1.username in (t2.blocker, t2.blocked)` to match either column when joining.

Comment: I don't need to match either, I need to match both. If i match one its not going to return the results of the other.

Comment: Then use `ON t1.username = t2.blocker AND t1.username = t2.blocked` to match both. This is basic SQL.

Comment: Asking questions specific to my problem on a 2 year old question that doesn't really relate to my problem seems the wrong way to go about this, but sense you won't reopen my different question.... how do I select all members that are not a given user while joining on a table where we are matching where all members are the given user. In other words, who do I do a WHERE clause where t1.username <> 'user' while doing a join on the username. There needs to be a username to match else it always returns empty.

Comment: I've reopened your question. But the whole point of this idiom is that you match on username, but because it's a `LEFT JOIN` it returns `NULL` for all the columns in the second table when there's no match, and then you test that in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Bruce Try to understand the **logic** of it, rather than just copying code. If you understand how it works, you'll be able to generalize to many different cases.

Comment: I love how people just assume things, I am trying to understand the logic, thats why I am not understanding the code. To do a join, you have to have some data that actually matches. A join won't work if you are trying to exclude the very result you need to join. IE. if I exclude username in my whereclause, how can I join using the username as its never going to match.

Comment: Read about the difference between `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @Bruce I've added a detailed explanation of how the second query works.

Comment: @Barmar http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5 This is every type of table join, including the cross join (mysql does not have a "full table join" per say). I understand joins. I use them all the time. I cannot get the desired result for my specific question. So. I am going back to my question instead of continuing a conversational howto thread here.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness (and I honestly believe it fits better), I encourage you to use a simple `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT * FROM reservation R
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM reservation_log
  WHERE reservation_id = R.id
    AND change_type = 'cancel'
);
```