# Data in condition is not equal

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select all records in the table `t2` which `t2.t1_id` has no coincidence with `t1.id`.

```
SELECT * FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id <> t2.t1_id
```

Any tips, link or code example would be useful.

Comment: Can you post table information and an example of the data you want to get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return row only if value doesnt exists \[MYSQL\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exists-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is all t2 records without a matching id in t1, but no columns from t1, you could do:

```
 Select * from t2
 WHERE t2.t1_id NOT IN(Select id from T1)
```

This selects all records in t2, but then filters out those that exist in t1 based on t1_id

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `not in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t2
WHERE  t2.t1_id not in (select id from t1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM t2 
LEFT JOIN t1 
    ON t1.id = t2.t1_id 
where t1.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add, `NOT EXIST` is better in most cases:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t2
WHERE  NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM t1
                            WHERE t2.t1_id = t1.id)
```

Otherwise, you can use `NOT IN` or `LEFT JOIN with NULL`