# not equal to - MySQL explicit not having and group

Tags: mysql

I am looking for SQL syntax that can list "not having / or not equal to values", however my requirement 
should group results by Name and list only the names that doesn't have "not having / or not equal to values"

When i run

```
SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE promo_name != 'barbie';
```

I get following result:

```
d   Name            promo_name      Remarks
2   Male Adult      Anniversary     NULL
3   Female Adult    Valentines Day  NULL
4   Boy             Play Station    NULL
5   Old Guy         Retirement      NULL
7   Girl            Skirts          NULL
8   Girl            Chocolates      NULL
9   Girl            Christmas       NULL
10  Male Adule      Valentines Day  NULL
11  Male Adule      Christmas       NULL
12  Female Adult    Christmas       NULL
13  Boy             Christmas       NULL
```

I am looking for a query that generates following result: with condition = `WHERE promo_name != 'barbie'`

```
d   Name            promo_name      Remarks
2   Male Adult                      NULL
3   Female Adult                    NULL
4   Boy                             NULL
5   Old Guy                         NULL
6   Old Lady                        NULL
```

Another example

```
WHERE promo_name != 'Christmas';
```

looking for result like below:

```
2   Male Adult                      NULL
5   Old Guy                         NULL
6   Old Lady                        NULL
```

I am attaching sql dump below.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`promotions` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `promo_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Remarks` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

USE test; 

insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (1,'Girl','Barbie',' ');
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (2,'Male Adult','Anniversary',' ');
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (3,'Female Adult','Valentines Day',' ');
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (4,'Boy','Play Station',' ');
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (5,'Old Guy','Retirement',' ');
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (6,'Old Lady',null,'');
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (7,'Girl','Skirts',null);
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (8,'Girl','Chocolates',null);
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (9,'Girl ','Christmas',null);
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (10,'Male Adule','Valentines Day',null);
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (11,'Male Adule','Christmas',null);
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (12,'Female Adult','Christmas',null);
insert into `promotions`(`id`,`Name`,`promo_name`,`Remarks`) values (13,'Boy','Christmas',null);
```

Comment: You really need to describe what you're looking for a bit more clearly.

Comment: you can use `WHERE promo_name NOT IN('barbie', 'Christmas',....)` if you want use multiple not equal condition

Comment: Your main concern with the group by name right!.can you please describe bit more clear

Comment: SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE promo_name NOT IN ('barbie','Christmas');

Comment: Thanks Grish and Fortune, i understand NOT IN ('{}') works, but there are some situations there may be several hundreds of "not in", is there another option.    Hello Vamshi.goli can you Please let me know where and what can i describe more?

Comment: in this query  Another example > 
" WHERE promo_name != 'Christmas';  " 
looking for result like below:                                            2   Male Adult                      NULL
5   Old Guy                         NULL
6   Old Lady                        NULL      Here can you explain on what basis you have given result

Comment: in the above results of SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE promo_name != 'barbie'..................in the result why you didn't took 'girl' according to your query it has to be there right!!!!!!....the results what you need are no stability

Comment: I found right answer already answered earlier (Feb 7 '14 at 16:43). Thank you Barmar 
 
[it is available here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist) 

This answer is in fact what i exactly i wanted. Well done Barmar

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand (didn't get your problem entirely, but it seems though) you don't want promo_name column, so don't use `*`,  if you want just two columnns

use their names as

```
select Name,     Remarks from promotions where promo_name!='barbie'
```

Comment: Hi Codeek, result should have 1 unique name that doesn't have specific promo_name. i.e. if i am looking for != 'Christmas' result should have unique users who don't have promo_name 'Christmas' and user should be excluded if he/she is in other promo but not in 'Christmas'. i want result specific to only 1 promo_name only. I wish i can explain better. <br> this looks simple but please look it up 1 more time.. this is tricky and complex... :)

Comment: I found right answer already answered earlier (Feb 7 '14 at 16:43). Thank you Barmar 
 
[it is available here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist) 

This answer is in fact what i exactly i wanted. Well done Barmar

Comment: glad you found it :), happy coding and happy new year