# Find rows in a table that do not have a relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where column A and column B have some kind of relationship.
The relationship is defined by the rule that the majority of all rows where column A is X column B will be Y.

The table may look like this:

```
| columnA | columnB  |
+---------+----------+
|  Katze  |   Cat    |
|  Katze  |   Cat    |
|  Katze  |   hkjhkj |
|  Katze  |   Cat    |
|  Hund   |   Dog    |
|  Hund   |   Dog    |
|  Hund   |   werw   |
```

How can I find the non fitting rows 3 and 7 here?

Comment: Use group with count, and select the top row of a DESC order on the count

Comment: Start by writing a query that finds the most common value of `columnB` for each `columnA`. Put this in a subquery. Then find the rows that don't match this, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exists-mysql?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is count the number of times each pair exists like this:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, COUNT(*) AS numAppearances
FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnA, columnB;
```

If you only want to see rows that appear once, use a HAVING clause to get those:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, COUNT(*) AS numAppearances
FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnA, columnB
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66b09/1) example.

Comment: Great first suggestion, Thank you. But first one shows me all. And second one just works if I have not to identical wrong pairs like "Katze  |   hkjhkj". I think about finding a threshold like HAVING COUNT(*) < 4;

Comment: @midnight the first one was meant to be a demonstration on how to get the number of combinations, and the second one is my answer for how to get ones that do not have good pairs. Isn't that what you wanted? You said rows 3 and 7 and I returned them.

Comment: Dont get me wrong. I am already pretty happy. But in the real table I probably have several identical wrong, so  COUNT(*) = 1 will not work.

Comment: I think http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3304/4/0  will work for me with count <50 because the good rows will have a count bigger 50.

Comment: @midnight The value used for having can be changed to whatever you need. Does the query itself work for you though?

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac67a/2

```
SELECT t4.id, t4.columnA, t4.columnB 
FROM (
SELECT t.columnA,MAX(t1.major) correct
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) as major
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY columnA, columnB
) t1
ON t.columnA = t1.columnA
  AND t.columnB = t1.columnB
GROUP BY t.columnA) t3
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) as major
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY columnA, columnB
) t4
ON t3.columnA = t4.ColumnA
  AND t3.correct>t4.major
```