# How would I make this more efficient?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include "../get/header.php";
$Username = SecurePost($_GET['Username']);
$gU = mysqli_fetch_object($getUser = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$Username."'"));
$UserExist = mysqli_num_rows($getUser = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$Username."'"));
$getUsers = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Users");
$numUsers = mysqli_num_rows($getUsers); 
$reqKills = mysqli_num_rows($allKills = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Kills WHERE Killer='".$gU->Username."'")); 
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE Users SET Kills='".$reqKills."' WHERE Username='".$gU->Username."'");
$pID = file_get_contents('http://rproxy.pw/rapi/GetIdByUsername/'.$gU->Username.'');
$Rank = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=GetGroupRole&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=947351');

$getTemp = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='983872'");
$numTemp = mysqli_num_rows($getTemp); 

$Tact = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='976897'");
$numTac = mysqli_num_rows($Tact); 

$Sci = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='986292'");
$numSci = mysqli_num_rows($Sci); 

$MAC = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='1045203'");
$NumMAC = mysqli_num_rows($MAC); 

$Ops = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='1159559'");
$numOps = mysqli_num_rows($Ops); 

$Eng = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='990439'");
$numEng = mysqli_num_rows($Eng); 

$Diplo = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='992455'");
$numDip = mysqli_num_rows($Diplo); 

$Intel = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='974799'");
$numIntel = mysqli_num_rows($Intel); 

$realIA = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Branchs WHERE Username='".$Username."' AND GroupID='2640969'");
$numIA = mysqli_num_rows($realIA); 
#GroupAssign#
$Temporal = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=983872');
$Tactical = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=976897');
$Science = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=986292');
$MACO = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=1045203');
$Operations = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=1159559');
$Engineering = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=990439');
$IA = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=2640969');
$Diplomatic = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=992455');
$Intelligence = file_get_contents('http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid='.$pID.'&groupid=974799');

if ($Temporal == true AND $numTemp == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','Temporal Investigations','Temporal','983872')");
}
if ($Tactical == true AND $numTac == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','Tactical Command','Tactical','976897')");
}
if ($Science == true AND $numSci == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','Applied Sciences','Science','986292')");
}
if ($MACO == true AND $NumMAC == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','MACO','MACO','1045203')");
}
if ($Operations == true AND $numOps == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','Operations','Operations','1159559')");
}
if ($Engineering == true AND $numEng == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','Engineering','Engineering','990439')");
}
if ($IA == true AND $numIA == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','Internal Affairs','IA','2640969')");
}
if ($Diplomatic == true AND $numDip == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','Diplomatic Corps','Diplomatic','992455')");
}
if ($Intelligence == true AND $numIntel == "0") {
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID) VALUES('".$gU->Username."','Starfleet Intelligence','Intelligence','974799')");
}
?>
```

As you can see its very inefficient, and only works for the first Temporal query for some reason.  Is there any way I can simplify this to be more efficient and make the values work for each query? I haven't received any errors.

Comment: one query ..`AND GROUP ID IN (983872,976897 ...)...`

Answer (score 0):

This query will insert a row into `Branchs` for each group that doesn't exist for `$Username`.

```
INSERT INTO Branchs (Username, Name, Image, GroupID)
SELECT '{$gU->Username}', groups.Name, groups.Image, groups.GroupID
FROM (
    SELECT '983872' AS GroupID, 'Temporal Investigations' AS Name, 'Temporal' AS Image
    UNION
    SELECT '976892', 'Tactical Command', 'Tactical'
    UNION
    SELECT '986292', 'Applied Sciences', 'Science'
    ...
    ) AS groups
LEFT JOIN Branchs ON Branches.GroupID = groups.GroupID AND Username = '$Username'
WHERE Branchs.GroupID IS NULL
```

See [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exists-mysql?lq=1) for how the `LEFT JOIN` works to return rows in the `UNION` subquery that don't have matches in `Branchs`.