# select count DISTINCT where != 2 filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has **eventid** (alarm Event id) and eventtype (`active = 1, Ack = 2, unack = 0`). I  would like to show a count of unacknowledged alarms.

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT eventid) FROM alarm_events where eventtype != 2
```

[image]

Not sure how i filter out the eventid that has been acknowledged

Comment: ha - Its my first time trying to use this forum.  Sorry about that

Comment: unacknowledged alarms ???

Comment: Text is usually preferable to images when it comes to SQL data, because the former allows users to copy the data out.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT eventid)
FROM alarm_events
WHERE eventid NOT IN (
    SELECT eventid
    FROM alarm_events
    WHERE eventtype = 2)
```

or equivalently

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.eventid)
FROM alarm_events AS a
LEFT JOIN alarm_events AS b ON a.eventid = b.eventid AND b.eventtype = 2
WHERE b.eventid IS NULL
```

See [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exists-mysql?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT eventid) FROM alarm_events where eventtype in (1,0)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Group By and for filtering you can use IN operator.

```
SELECT count(eventid) FROM alarm_events WHERE eventtype in (0, 1) GROUP BY eventid
```

> Pl replace (0, 1) with ('0','1') if your eventtype column is String.