# Mysql - Not In takes Time when nested select query is dynamic but not if it's constant

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

T1 contains about 30 million rows,
T2 contains about 100k rows

```
select a from T2 gives ('a1','a2','a3',...); (1 lakh rows)
```

When I use 100k constant values directly inside the in block the query returns result in 80 millisec. But, when I use nested select in the query, it takes like forever.

```
select a,b from T1 where a in ('a1','a2','a3', ...); (Constant Values inside in block)  
select a,b from T1 where a in (select a from T2); (Query instead of values)
```

Any Idea why is it happening? Also is there a better way to do so?
Since T1 contains 30 million rows, Left Join also takes a lot of time.

My Actual Query is :

```
select a,b from t1 where (a,b) not in (select a,b from t2) and a in (select a from t1);
```

Comment: do an `explain` of the query. you'll probably see mysql's creating a temp table/using filesort, which takes time. and note for this kind of thing, you'd be better of just using a `join`. `select a,b from t1 join t2 on t1.whatever=t2.whatever`

Comment: Thanks, Also considering the fact t1 can have 3crore rows and t2 some lakh rows. My actual query is : select a,b from t1 where (a,b) not in (select a,b from t2) and a in (select a from t1); I need an optimised one.

Comment: Your title talks about `NOT IN`, yet your code says `IN`?  Which is it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1 for how to do the `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` better.

Comment: I have added my actual query which contains both NOT IN and IN

Answer (score 0):

There is a third, better, way:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM T1
    JOIN T2  ON T1.a = T2.a;
```

(And be sure that there is an index on `a` in each table.)

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is notoriously slow; avoid it.

Comment: A simple inner join isn't a good substitute for `IN ( SELECT ... )` because the former won't do a semi-join properly.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is more expensive in MySQL because MySQL hasn't optimized that type of query very well. MySQL doesn't notice that the subquery is *invarant*, in other words the subquery on T2 has the same result regardless of which row of T1 is being searched. So you and I can see clearly that MySQL should execute the subquery once and use its result to evaluate each row of T1.

But in fact, MySQL naively assumes that the subquery is a *correlated subquery* that may have a different result for each row in T1. So it is forced to run the subquery many times.

You clarified in a comment that your query is actually:

```
select a,b from t1 
where (a,b) not in (select a,b from t2) 
    and a in (select a from t1);
```

You should also know that MySQL does not optimize tuple comparison at all. Even if it should use an index, it will do a table-scan. I think they're working on fixing that in MySQL 8.

Your second term is unnecessary, because the subquery is selecting from `t1`, so obviously any value of `a` in `t1` exists in `t1`. <strike>Did you mean to put `t2` in the subquery? I'll assume that you just made an error typing.</strike>

Here's how I would write your query:

```
select a, b from t1
left outer join (select distinct a, b from t2) as nt2 
    on t1.a = nt2.a and t1.b = nt2.b
where nt2.a is null;
```

In these cases, MySQL treats the subquery differently because it appears in the `FROM` clause. It runs each subquery once and stores the results in temp tables. Then it evaluates the rows of `t1` against the data in the temp tables.

The use of `distinct` is to make sure to do the *semi-join* properly; if there are multiple matching rows in `t2`, we don't want multiple rows of output from the query.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. Yes the second term is not required, the query should be  only the following :                                                                                     select a,b from t1 where (a,b) not in (select a,b from t2)

Comment: It is giving error : Column 'a' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Qualify column names like `t1.a` to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, it worked. But the query is still taking a lot of time. When I directly put the data from (select a,b from t2) i.e. the second part it runs very quickly.

Comment: Yes, subqueries are pretty costly in MySQL. Perhaps you should do two queries: the first to query `select a, b from t2` and the second to use the result as literal values.