# php PDO MySQL Select results of one table based on array of results from another table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following query will return all "blocker" users and all "blocked" users. Fairly straight forward query.

```
$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT blocker,blocked FROM list_blocked 
                    WHERE (blocked = :username AND blocker <> :username) 
                    OR (blocker = :username AND blocked <> :username)');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
```

The next query will return all usernames from the members table except the current $username.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username <> :username");
$query->bindValue(':user', $username;
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll();
```

What I need is a way to get all the values from the results of the first query, excluding the active $username, and then exclude all those results from the second query.

So for example:

```
Example results of first query:
jim blocked joe
larry blocked joe
steve blocked joe
joe blocked tony
jack blocked joe

Those results applied to the second query would look something like:
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username <> :username 
                       AND username <> jim 
                       AND username <> larry
                       AND username <> steve
                       AND username <> tony
                       AND username <> jack");
```

How exactly would I achieve something like this?

**UPDATE:**

So I am trying to use a subquery but it keeps returning *"Operand should contain 1 column(s)"*

```
SELECT username FROM members WHERE username NOT IN (
    SELECT blocker,blocked FROM list_blocked 
                           WHERE (blocked = 'viraladmin' AND blocker <> 'viraladmin') 
                           OR (blocker = 'viraladmin' AND blocked <> 'viraladmin')
 )
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

I attempted to use an inner join to achieve this, however the results always return empty, which I assume is because there is actually nothing to join.

```
SELECT members.username, list_blocked.blocker, list_blocked.blocked
FROM members
INNER JOIN list_blocked 
ON members.username = list_blocked.blocker
AND members.username = list_blocked.blocked
WHERE members.username <>  'username' 
AND (list_blocked.blocked = 'username' AND list_blocked.blocker <> 'username') 
OR (list_blocked.blocker = 'username' AND list_blocked.blocked <> 'username')
```

Comment: Why not use something like a subquery to determine what not to select?

Comment: @Blake Well the answer is, because I have no clue how to do that, thats perhaps what I am hoping to learn. :)

Comment: Certainly if someone threw you a google bone, you could do it though.

Comment: When you mix `AND` and `OR` in a `WHERE` clause, you need to be very careful to use parentheses, because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a sub query:

```
SELECT username FROM members WHERE username NOT IN (
SELECT blocker,blocked FROM list_blocked 
                WHERE (blocked = :username AND blocker <> :username) 
                OR (blocker = :username AND blocked <> :username)
 )
```

Edited - to fit a SQL query you would need to union in the subquery so the results return no more then one column.  :

```
SELECT username FROM members WHERE username NOT IN (
   SELECT blocker as username FROM list_blocked 
                WHERE (blocked = :username AND blocker <> :username) 
                OR (blocker = :username AND blocked <> :username)
   UNION
   SELECT blocked as username FROM list_blocked 
                WHERE (blocked = :username AND blocker <> :username) 
                OR (blocker = :username AND blocked <> :username)
 )
```

Comment: I actually don't think this would work because of the multiple column selection in the sub query.

Comment: Ironically the first solution didn't work because they removed my second column selection from their query, and this solution doesn't work, because it returns an error.

Comment: Bruce, since you are concerned with only the usernames from the blocking table, try doing a union, which will join the two results as a single column.  I think that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `LEFT JOIN - NULL` pattern for this.

```
SELECT username
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN list_blocked AS b
ON m.username IN (b.blocker, b.blocked)
    AND ((blocked = :username AND blocker <> :username) 
        OR (blocker = :username AND blocked <> :username))
WHERE b.blocked IS NULL
```

This is based on the pattern in [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1)