# Executing an update and checking for duplicates at same time in MySQL/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2 and have a query:

```
    DB::table('data')->whereIn('t_id', $new_ids);
                ->whereNotIn('l_id', $old_ids);
                ->groupBy('l_id')->update(array('t_id' => $new_t_id));
```

This causes an error:

```
500 - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1569648-7302' for key 'data_l_id_t_id_unique' (SQL: update `data` set `t_id` = 7302 where `t_id` in (4772, 4860, 4861, 5653, 6396, 6743) and `l_id` not in (2994190)) @ /
```

The problems seems to be with `groupBy()` clause which is not being executed, thus making duplicate l_id to be pulled into the query:

```
mysql> select l_id from data where t_id=7302;
+---------+
| l_id |
+---------+
| 2994190 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select l_id from data where t_id in (4772, 4860, 4861, 5653, 6396, 6743);
+---------+
| l_id |
+---------+
| 1569648 |
| 1593870 |
| 1594096 |
| 1628872 |
| 1569648 |
| 1593870 |
| 1594096 |
| 1628872 |
| 1569648 |
| 1593870 |
| 1594096 |
| 1628872 |
| 1879092 |
| 2283518 |
| 2284586 |
| 2604466 |
+---------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select l_id from data where t_id in (4772, 4860, 4861, 5653, 6396, 6743) GROUP BY l_id;
+---------+
| l_id |
+---------+
| 1569648 |
| 1593870 |
| 1594096 |
| 1628872 |
| 1879092 |
| 2283518 |
| 2284586 |
| 2604466 |
+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Schema:

```
mysql> show create table data;

CREATE TABLE `data` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`l_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`t_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `data_l_id_tag_id_unique` (`l_id`,`t_id`),
KEY `data_t_id_foreign` (`t_id`),
CONSTRAINT `data_l_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`l_id`) REFERENCES `lis` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `data_t_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`t_id`) REFERENCES `tas` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4544794 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Basically I need to update **t_id** for certain **l_id**s but still ensure no duplicate t_id/l_id happen. I could do this by looping through each t_id and checking for duplicates before updating but thought a shortcut via `groupBy()` would be a better way of doing it.

Is it possible to make Laravel do a `groupBy()` while updating? More generally can an update be executed while checking for duplicates, even in plain SQL?

**Edit: Separating update from group by**

Making UPDATE and GROUP BY seperate helps  resolve GROUP BY problem but not duplicate problem:

```
    $required_l_ids = DB::table('data')->whereIn('t_id', $new_ids);
                ->whereNotIn('l_id', $old_ids);
                ->groupBy('l_id')->lists('l_id');


    if ( !empty($required_l_ids) ) {
            DB::table('data')->whereIn('l_id', $required_l_ids)->whereIn('t_id', $new_ids)->update(array('t_id' => $new_tag_id));
    }
```

Still gives an error:

```
500 - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1593870-7302' for key 'data_l_id_t_id_unique' (SQL: update `data` set `t_id` = 7302 where `l_id` in (1593870, 1594096, 1628872, 1879092, 2283518, 2284586, 2604466) and `t_id` in (4772, 4860, 4861, 5653, 6396, 6743)) @ /
```

**Edit 2: Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`l_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`t_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `data_l_id_t_id_unique` (`l_id`,`t_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4544794 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1569648,7302);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (2994190,7302);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1593870,4772);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1594096,4772);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1628872,4772);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1569648,4860);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1593870,4860);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1594096,4860);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1628872,4860);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1569648,4861);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1593870,4861);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1594096,4861);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1628872,4861);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (1879092,5653);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (2283518,6396);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (2284586,6396);
INSERT into data (l_id, t_id) VALUES (2604466,6743);


UPDATE data AS d1 LEFT JOIN data AS d2 ON d1.l_id = d2.l_id AND d2.t_id = 7302 SET d1.t_id = 7302 WHERE d1.t_id IN (4772,4860,4861,5653,6396,6743) AND d1.l_id NOT IN (1569648,2994190) AND d2.l_id IS NULL;
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9a50

**Error**: `Duplicate entry '1593870-7302' for key 'data_l_id_t_id_unique'`

Comment: Separate update operation from group by method?

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek I tried separating `groupBy()` and `update` but still ended up with duplicate error, though it resolved the `groupBy`. See updated question.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is for combining rows when you're selecting data. It makes no sense to use it when updating. Even if it worked, how would it solve your problem of not creating duplicates?

Comment: @Barmar Other than  looping though each t_id and checking for duplicates on each, how can one make an update and still ensure no duplicates happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the Laravel syntax, but I think this is the MySQL syntax for what you want:

```
UPDATE data AS d1
JOIN (SELECT l_id, MIN(t_id) AS min_t_id
      FROM data
      WHERE d1.t_id IN ($new_ids)
      AND d1.l_id NOT IN ($old_ids)
      GROUP BY l_id) AS d3 ON d1.l_id = d3.l_id AND d1.t_id = d3.min_t_id
LEFT JOIN data AS d2 ON d1.l_id = d2.l_id AND d2.t_id = $new_tag_id
SET d1.t_id = $new_tag_id
WHERE d2.l_id IS NULL
```

This combines an `UPDATE` with the `LEFT JOIN/NULL` pattern in [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1)

The first `JOIN` makes sure that only one row for each `l_id` is updated, so you don't create duplicates. It arbitrarily chooses the lowest `t_id` to replace.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ce7a/2)

Comment: Plain SQL is still fine. But the query you gave gives `ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 't_id' in where clause is ambiguous
` and `ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'l_id' in where clause is ambiguous`, If I put d1,t_id and d2.l_id I get `Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0` which means no duplicates but nothing getting updated

Comment: Fixed. I originally wrote this using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, then changed it to `LEFT JOIN`, and forgot to add all the aliases.

Comment: The plain SQL also gives duplicate error: `UPDATE data AS d1 LEFT JOIN data AS d2 ON d1.l_id = d2.l_id AND d2.t_id = 7302 SET d1.t_id = 7302 WHERE d1.t_id IN (4772,4860,4861,5653,6396,6743) AND d1.l_id NOT IN (1569648,2994190) AND d2.l_id IS NULL;` gives `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1593870-7302' for key 'data_l_id_t_id_unique'`

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data.

Comment: Updated question with sample data

Comment: I see the problem. My query prevents creating duplicates of existing rows, but if there are multiple rows with the same `l_id`, it will try to update all of them with the new `t_id`, and that creates duplicates. So it should only update one of them. How should it decide which?

Comment: The way to do it is to join with a query that selects that row.

Comment: If there are duplicates only one need to get updated and others ignored. It doesn't matter which one. What's important is that the l_id will be associated with new t_id.

Comment: Have to go now, I'll post the updated query late tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add a join with a subquery that selects one row per `l_id`. sqlfiddle.com is acting up so I haven't been able to test it yet.

Comment: sqlfiddle is back, I've added a demo.