# Rewriting a query that has two sub queries using no sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the database schema:

```
Part( PID, PName, Producer, Year, Price)
Customer( CID, CName, Province)
Supply(SID, PID, CID, Quantity, Amount, Date)
```

And the query:

```
Select cname, Province
From Customer c
Where exists (
    Select * 
    from Supply s
    join Part p on p.pId = s.pId 
    Where CId = c.CId 
    and p.Producer = 'Apple'
)
and Not exists (
    Select * 
    from Supply n
    join Part nap on nap.pId = n.pId 
    Where CId = c.CId 
    and nap.Producer != 'Apple'
)
```

How would I go about rewriting this query without the two sub queries?

Comment: your query looks fine to me. why you want to rewrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN/NULL` pattern to find customers who haven't bought any non-Apple products. Then you can do this all with just joins. You'll have to join with `Supply` and `Parts` twice, once for finding Apple products, then again for excluding non-Apple products.

```
SELECT distinct c.name, c.province
FROM Customer AS c
JOIN Supply AS s1 ON s1.cid = c.cid
JOIN Parts AS p1 ON p1.pid = s1.pid
LEFT JOIN Supply AS s2 ON s2.cid = c.cid
LEFT JOIN Parts AS p2 ON p2.pid = s2.pid AND p2.producer != 'Apple'
WHERE p1.producer = 'Apple' AND p2.pid IS NULL
```

Notice that in the `LEFT JOIN` you put restrictions of the second table in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause. See [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1) for more about this part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You want customer who only bought Apple products?

One possible solution is based on conditional aggregation:

```
Select c.cname, c.Province
From Customer c
join
 ( -- this is not a Subquery, it's a Derived Table
   Select s.CId -- assuming there's a CId in Supply
   from Supply s
   join Part p
     on p.pId = s.pId
   group by s.CId 
   -- when there's any other supplier this will return 1
   having max(case when p.Producer = 'Apple' then 0 else 1 end) = 0
 ) as p
on p.CId = c.CId
```