# mysql left join respect condition of all row joined

Tags: mysql

i have two table, fos_user and zone
with

- `fos_user` { `id`, `name`, `enabled`}
- `zone` {`id`, `fos_user_id`, `enabled`}

for each `fos_user` can exists more than `zone`

i need to filter `fos_users` that have ONLY `zone` with `enabled=1`

i try with

```
SELECT * FROM fos_user as u
LEFT JOIN zona as z ON u.id=z.users_id
WHERE z.enabled=1 AND  u.enabled=1
```

but i get a list of `fos_user` that have almost one zone with `enabled=1`

how i can fix?

thank you

Comment: What if a user has no `zone` records?

Answer (score 3):

You can group by user and compare the number of enabled zones against the total number of zones:

```
SELECT *
  FROM fos_user u
  JOIN zone z ON u.id = z.users_id
 WHERE u.enabled = 1
 GROUP BY u.id
HAVING SUM(z.enabled = 1) = COUNT(*);
```

Comment: If user has no `zone` records and you want to include it as valid `SUM` record, the `z.enabled` value would be `NULL`, to make it count just do: `HAVING SUM(IFNULL(z.enabled = 1, 1)) = COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1):

You need a second condition to exclude users in non-enabled zones.

```
SELECT *
FROM fos_user AS u
INNER JOIN zone AS z on u.id = z.users_id
LEFT JOIN zone AS z1 on u.id = z1.users_id AND z1.enabled = 0
WHERE u.enabled = 1 AND z.enabled = 1
AND z1.id IS NULL
```

You use `INNER JOIN` to match zones exactly, and you use `LEFT JOIN` with a `NULL` test to find users that *don't* match that criteria (see [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1)).