# Remove results from SELECT by conditions on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this feed of products

```
id man sup product
1  1   1   MacBook
2  1   2   iMac
3  2   1   Windows
4  2   2   Office
```

and then tables with manufacturers

```
id manufacturer
1  Apple
2  Microsoft
```

and suppliers

```
id supplier
1  TechData
2  Westcoast
```

Then, for some reasons, I don't want to show a manufacturer's products by a certain supplier, i.e.:

```
id man sup comment
1  2   1   TechData aren't allowed to sell Microsoft 
2  1   2   hide all Apple products from Westcoast
```

Is there a way, in pure SQL, to show only the products which fall through my filter, in this case MacBook and Office? I believe this isn's just a `WHERE NOT (x AND y)` as the result will list the remaining combinations.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why isn't this `WHERE NOT (x AND y)`?  That seems like the logic you are describing.

Comment: Because the select generates a matrix of all combinations, with only these removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a variation on [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1), except you're joining on two columns.

```
SELECT p.product, m.manufacturer, s.supplier
FROM products AS p
JOIN manufacturers AS m ON m.id = p.man
JOIN suppliers AS s ON s.id = p.sup
LEFT JOIN filter AS f ON p.man = f.man AND p.sup = f.sup
WHERE f.id IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5f49/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, mate:

First, create the `temporary/real` container for your custom manufacturer-supplier filter:

```
-- pivot temp/real table for suppliers - manufacturers
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `manufacturers_suppliers`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `manufacturers_suppliers` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `manufacturer_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, 
    `supplier_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`manufacturer_id` ASC, `supplier_id` ASC)
);
-- populate pivot table
INSERT INTO `manufacturers_suppliers` (`manufacturer_id`, `supplier_id`)
VALUES 
    -- TechData aren't allowed to sell Microsoft 
    (2, 1), 
    -- hide all Apple products from Westcoast
    (1, 2);
```

After that, using the content of the container, you only need to create a standard query for your result set.

```
-- create result
SELECT 
    p.id, p.product,        # show product detail
    s.id, s.supplier,       # show supplier detail
    m.id, m.manufacturer    # show manufacturer detail
FROM
    products p
    INNER JOIN suppliers s ON s.id = p.sup
    INNER JOIN manufacturers m ON m.id = p.man
    LEFT JOIN `manufacturers_suppliers` ms ON 
        ms.manufacturer_id = man.id
        AND ms.supplier_id = sup.id
WHERE ms.id IS NULL;
```

So that every time you have an update to your filter, you only update `records` not the actual `query script`. Cheers

Comment: Btw, depending on your requirements, you can either use a `normal` or `temporary` table.