# MySQL : IF EXISTS THEN UPDATE ELSE INSERT from one table to another using IF ELSE statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `user` & `user_tmp` having primary key as `id` only. The fields of both the tables are likely as :

```
`id` PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT INT,
`Name` VARCHAR(80),
`Contact No` VARCHAR(10),
`Status` INT
```

I need a simple query based on IF EXISTS ON `user_tmp` table THEN update value in `user` ELSE insert in `user` table.

I tried with REPLACE & ON DUPLICATE KEY, but it din't work as `id` is the PRIMARY KEY and the value varies in both the tables.

Regards.

Comment: if `id` value doesn't match in two tables how can you distinguish unique records?

Comment: Hi Alexey, this is based on `Contact_No`, which is also not a contraint

Comment: How about adding it as a unique key to user table and using `on duplicate key update` ?

Comment: There is an instruction not to change the table structure.

Comment: You can't use `REPLACE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY` unless the column you're testing is a unique column. If you can't make `make `Contact_No` unique, you can't do this in pure SQL. You'll need to write a stored procedure to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it as two queries. One query to update the records that match:

```
UPDATE user AS u
JOIN user_tmp AS t ON u.Contact_No = t.Contact_no
SET u.Name = t.Name, u.Status = t.Status;
```

and a second to insert the ones that don't already exist:

```
INSERT INTO user (Name, Contact_No, Status)
SELECT t.Name, t.Contact_No, t.Status
FROM user_tmp AS t
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.Contact_No = t.Contact_no
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

See [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1) for an explanation of how the `SELECT` query in the `INSERT` works to find rows that don't match.