# SQL pseudo query

Tags: sql

Three data tables A, B and C. 
A and B share a common variable ID1. 
B and C share a common variable ID2. 
Write a pseudo query to get this result: select everything from Table B, with matching records in both Table A and B, but not in Table C.

I am new to sql and i'd really appreciate the help

Comment: Ask a *specific* question.  Don't just dump your homework assignment here and expect us to do it.

Comment: What's a pseudo query? It sounds like you really need to write a `JOIN`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1 for how to select records that don't match table C.

Answer (score 1):

We can't do your homework for you, but here's some direction for learning: Table A and Table B will be joined with a basic inner join on the ID1 column.

The trickier part is excluding results from A and B if they exist in Table C. For that you can do an outer join, and add a where clause to find the null values of table C. This is because when you do an outer join (for this example, we'll use a **left** outer join), it will pull all of the appropriate records from the left table, and then *try* to pull matching records from the right table. But if the record doesn't exist in the right table, then it will return a record with "null" values.

Your query would be:

```
SELECT
    table_b.* -- "select all from table B"
FROM
    table_a INNER JOIN table_b ON (table_a.ID1 = table_b.ID1) -- "matching records in A and B"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c ON (table_b.ID2 = table_c.ID2) -- Bring in table C to let us check if B's rows exist in C
WHERE
    table_c.ID2 IS NULL -- Only display records that don't have a corresponding C record
```

The key to "selecting records that in B and not C" is understanding outer joins.