# MySQL - in one table but not another - Wrong Results Displaying?

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables, `catalog` and `seriesTitle`.

I need to select instances of `SERIES_CODE` that exist in one table, but not the other, as follows:

```
SELECT SERIES_CODE 
FROM catalog 
WHERE SERIES_CODE NOT IN 
    (SELECT SERIES_CODE 
     FROM seriesTitle)
```

The query executes successfully, and results are returned.

However, the results are incomplete.  I am 100% positive that there are some `SERIES_CODE`s that exist in `catalog`, but not `seriesTitle`.

I have checked that the type and collation of `SERIES_CODE` is the same in both tables.

Is it possible there is some data corruption, or other issue other than the simple query above?  Or perhaps my query is wrong somehow?  (I'm not worried about performance right now, just results!)

Comment: SELECT SERIES_CODE 
FROM catalog  a
WHERE SERIES_CODE 
    (SELECT SERIES_CODE 
     FROM seriesTitle b where a.id!=b.id)

Comment: Please show some sample data which makes your problem reproducible.  Don't leave use guessing here.

Comment: The query syntax is fine, although I prefer using the `LEFT JOIN - NULL` pattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1