# my query needs to be slightly more specific

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

the question is 'List the pids of all properties that do not have the metertype “advanced”
installed. Use a sub-query in your answer.

[image: METERTYPE]  [image: PROPERTYMETER]

This is the query i came up with

```
SELECT PROPERTYMETER.pid, METERTYPE.description
 FROM PROPERTYMETER , METERTYPE
 WHERE PROPERTYMETER.metertype = METERTYPE.metertype
  AND description IN (SELECT description FROM METERTYPE WHERE description = 'conventional')
```

This is the result i got

[image]

The result is all good aside from the fact that pid 9 has both conventional and advanced metertype so i didnt really answer the question exactly right. What can i do to my query to make sure that the pid returned ONLY have metertype conventional?

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: Get the `pid`s of all the properties that have `metertype = advanced`. Then exclude them with a `NOT IN` test.

Comment: Did this and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery that gets the `pid`s of all the properties that have `metertype = 'advanced'`. Then use `NOT IN` to exclude them from the final result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pid
FROM propertymeter
WHERE pid NOT IN (
    SELECT pid
    FROM propertymeter AS p
    JOIN metertype AS m ON p.metertype = m.metertype
    WHERE m.description = 'advanced')
```

Comment: This also worked perfectly, is there any reason to use joins rather than multiple subqueries? i thin i read somewhere that joins offer better performance or are more efficient or something

Comment: Yes, MySQL doesn't always optimize `WHERE IN (subquery)` very well. The above `NOT IN` could also be written as a `LEFT JOIN/NULL` pattern, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1