# MySQL Between for newbs?

Tags: mysql

I don't know much about MySQL but I have to do sth. with this nice thing. :)
I have 1 Table with 2 ID Fields in it (ID and REFID).
I only want to select the ID's which are not between other ID to REFID.

Row 1: ID = 1 and REFID = 15

Row 2: ID = 17 and REFID = **20**

Row 3: ID = **19** and REFID = 25

I only want Row 1 and 2 in my result.
 because Row 3 is crossing Row 2.
Sorry for my bad explanation,
I hope you know what I want to know. :)

Comment: Why do you want row 2?

Comment: because its first!

Comment: 20 is not between 19 and 25 was how I was thinking.  So row two is out

Comment: 20 is not between 19 and 25? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the general pattern for finding a row in a table that doesn't match another table, as in [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1). But in this case the two tables are the same table, and the match is by checking for `id` being between `id` and `RefID` in the other row.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id > t2.id AND t1.id < t2.RefID
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a63f/1)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should use MySql procedures. You can find the tutorial [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this with PHP?

If so maybe something like this...
- create a query to return the desired columns of the table in an array ORDER by id
- then create a loop to start with get the records starting with the id equal to the lowest id number
- and repeat the loop until you have retrieved the record with the highest id number you desire.

- or use WHERE in the query to specify the id range you want returned.

One of these approaches should get you there... I think :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using php, too. But I thought it would be easier and cleaner to do this in db. The problem is,  that the Id Range changes every row.