# MySQL : Select all row of table depends on foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I don't know what is actual question, but my problem is given below ::

I have a MySQL table `table_name` something like this:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | name   | f_key |
+----+--------+--------
| 1  | abcd   |   0   |
| 2  | efgh   |   0   |
| 3  | ijkl   |   0   |
| 4  | mnop   |   2   |
+----+--------+-------+
```

`id` is primary key & `f_key` is foreign key [reference to id in same table].

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT f_key FROM table_name WHERE f_key !=0);
```

is there any other good (minimum execution time) MySQL query to get output like this:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | name   | f_key |
+----+--------+--------
| 1  | abcd   |   0   |
| 3  | ijkl   |   0   |
| 4  | mnop   |   2   |
+----+--------+-------+
```

EDIT ::

Try to make query for medium size result of sub query, but the problem is  :

- **EXISTS** executes at high speed against **IN** : when the subquery results
  is very large.
- **IN** gets ahead of **EXISTS** : when the subquery results is very small.

Comment: The second `SELECT *` should be `SELECT f_key`

Comment: Sorry, but corrected @Barmar

Comment: You should use btree index on your column name f_key for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

In Operator often has bad performance. I think you should try exists

```
    SELECT * FROM table_name a WHERE NOT Exists(SELECT f_key FROM table_name b WHERE b.f_key = a.id);
```

And if you can create index in f_key, this query will perform better

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal idiom for [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1) but with a self-join:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_name AS a
LEFT JOIN table_name AS b ON a.id = b.f_key
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) its is said, that the not in or an outer join would have a better performance, but [there](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) the not in or the not exists wins...

```
SELECT a.* FROM table_name a left outer join table_name b ON b.f_key = a.id
WHERE b.id is null
```