# SQL beginner practice problems

Tags: mysql, sql

Given two tables, `orders (order_id, date, $, customer_id)` and `customers (ID, name)`

Here's my method but I'm not sure if it's working & I'd like to know if there's faster/better way of solving these problems:

1) find out number of `customers` who made at least one `order` on `date` 7/9/2018

```
Select count (distinct customer_id)
From
(
Select customer_id from orders a 
Left join customer b
On a.customer_id = b.ID 
Group by customer_id,date
Having date = 7/9/2018
) a
```

2) find out number of `customers` who did not make an `order` on 7/9/2018

```
Select count (customer_id) from customer where customer_id not in
(
Select customer_id from orders a 
Left join customer b
On a.customer_id = b.ID 
Group by customer_id,date
Having date = 7/9/2018
)
```

3) find the `date` with most sales between 7/1 and 7/30

```
select date, max($)
from (
Select sum($),date from orders a 
Left join customer b
On a.customer_id = b.ID 
Group by date
Having date between 7/1 and 7/30
)
```

Thanks,

Comment: There is no date equal to 7 divided by 9 divided by 2018 :-(

Comment: Dates have to be put in quotes, and in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Query one is wrong it should be also using `COUNT(*) >= 1` in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: ...and the customers table is irrelevant to that problem

Comment: @Barmar Dates _should_ be in that format, but they don't have to be. As long as the server (through localization or whatever) can determine a date, it will read the string as a date. It may not be the expected date (1/2/2018 or 2/1/2018).

Answer (score 3):

For problem 1, a valid solution might look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) x
  FROM orders 
 WHERE date = '2018-09-07';  -- or is that '2018-07-09' ??
```

For problem 2, a valid solution might look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) x
  FROM customer c
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.customer_id = x.customer_id
   AND o.date = '2018-07-09'
 WHERE o.crder_id IS NULL;
```

Assuming there are no ties, a valid solution to problem 3 might look like this:

```
SELECT date 
     , COUNT(*) sales 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-30' 
 GROUP 
    BY date 
 ORDER 
    BY sales DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The default format for a date in MySQL is `YYYY-MM-DD`, although this can be customized. You have to put quotes around it, otherwise it's treated as an arithmetic expression.

And none of your queries need to join with the `customer` table. The customer ID is already in the `orders` table, and you're not returning any info about the customers (like the name or address), you're just counting them.

1) You don't need the subquery or grouping.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
FROM orders
WHERE date = '2018-07-09'
```

2) Again, you don't need `GROUP BY` in the subquery. There's also a better pattern than `NOT IN` to get the count of non-matching rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM customer AS c
LEFT JOIN order AS o on c.id = o.customer_id AND o.date = '2018-07-09'
WHERE o.id IS NULL
```

See [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1) for various patterns to do this.

3) You can't use `MAX($)` in the outer query because the inner query doesn't return a column with that name. But even if you fix that, it still won't work, because the `date` column won't necessarily come from the same row that has the maximum. See [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1) for more explanation of this.

You don't need a subquery at all. Use a query that returns the total sales for each day, then use `ORDER BY` to get the highest one.

```
SELECT date, SUM($) AS total_sales
FROM orders
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2017-07-30'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If "most sales" is supposed to mean "most number of sales", replace `SUM($)` with `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: SUM($) would (presumably) give the highest value extracted, which is not necessarily the same thing as 'most sales'

Comment: @Strawberry It depends on whether he means most number of sales or most value of sales. I've chosen to use the same interpretation as the OP.

Comment: @barmar would this work then select date, max(total_sales)
from (
Select sum($) as total_sales,date from orders a 
Left join customer b
On a.customer_id = b.ID 
Group by date
Having date between 7/1 and 7/30
)

Comment: if using a subquery instead of order/limit

Comment: @SQLLearner No. When you use an aggregation function like `max()` there's no guarantee that the non-aggregated column will come from the same row that has the max.

Comment: @BARMAR i know the solution posted work better, but my code for 1 and 2 should work as well? right?

Comment: Yes, they'll work as long as you fix the date syntax. But they're doing lots of unnecessary work.