# Need to speed up WHERE NOT EXISTS Query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I believe this is causing anywhere from a 5 minute to 20 minute delay depending on the number of records. I need to translate it into a LEFT JOIN but need some help getting it there.

```
qry_arr = array(':bill_type' => "INT");
$sql = "update ".$billing_table." c set c.bill_type = :bill_type";
$sql .= " WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT s.abbreviation FROM   state s WHERE  s.abbreviation = c.out_location)";
$sql .= " and c.out_location != 'UNKNOWN' and c.out_location != ''";
```

Comment: joins are almost always faster than sub-queries

Comment: @tim That's why he wants to convert it to a left join.

Comment: Yes, use a join.

Comment: Maybe `$sql = "update $billing_table c 
  left join state s
  on s.abbreviation = c.out_location
  set c.bill_type = :bill_type
  WHERE c.out_location != 'UNKNOWN' and c.out_location != ''"` Then you probably want `s.abbreviation` to be null for a non existent row

Comment: Does your table `billing_table` have an index on `out_location`? You should add it if not already present.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The $billing_table is created via php as well. I need to review that code to see how to add an index to it with something like INDEX i (g) at the end of the code. I am onsite for the next 14 hours so when I return I'll post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE $billing_table c
LEFT JOIN state s ON s.abbreviation = c.out_location
SET c.bill_type = :bill_type
WHERE s.abbreviation IS NULL
AND c.out_location NOT IN ('UNKNOWN', '')
```

This is essentially the same as the syntax for a `SELECT` for the rows that don't match. See [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1). Just replace `SELECT ... FROM` with `UPDATE`, and insert the `SET` clause before `WHERE`.

Make sure you have indexes on `out_location` and `abbreviation`.

Comment: Are indexes required here? The code creates the $billing_table table first with no columns, then in a second call parses a CSV file to get the column names and adds them to the table. This would be a 3rd SQL call to create the index on them. Something like CREATE INDEX out_location_index ON $billing_table([out_location]); s.abbreviation from the state table is a permanent table and is indexed with names abbreviation, abbreviation2. Do I need to give the out_location index a new name when creating the index and reference that in your code above?

Comment: It might not be needed. If most rows of `$billing_table` need to be processed, then a full scan of the table doesn't add much more overhead than using the index. To be sure, you'll have to benchmark it.

Comment: Will be testing this weekend and will update progress. Thanks!

Comment: This works but it turns out isn't where my slow code is. The code at the following link takes 31 minutes to run and needs the help. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935927/speed-up-sql-update-statement-that-is-looped-through-a-select-statement

Comment: Do you have the necessary indexes? Have you tried using `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan for the analogous `SELECT` query?

Comment: Definitely do not have indexes on these tables. EXPLAIN select id, did, customer_id from dids returns id = 1, select_type = SIMPLE, table = dids, type = ALL, possible_keys = NULL, key = NULL, key_len = NULL, ref = NULL, rows = 1955, Extra = ''

Comment: My answer says to make sure you have the necessary indexes. I'm not surprised it's slow without indexes.

Comment: Yup. your code is actually quick. It's the next set of code that is slow. Can I add indexes using their original column names as the index name like this? ALTER TABLE dids ADD INDEX did (did)

Comment: Sure you can. Column names and index names are independent.

Comment: In fact, if you don't give a name to the index, it automatically uses the column name by default.

Comment: Adding those 4 indexes makes the processing time drop from 30+ minutes to 40 seconds. Thank you!