# Query Many-to-Many relationship to see if one value exists but not another?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query a many to many relationship to see if one tag exists but not another. I'm trying to do this within one simple query.

I've asked a few friends and have checked stack overflow and can't seem to find someone who's trying to do something similar. I setup a SQLFiddle page which shows what I'm trying to do.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b741b/8

In the example I have three users: Mike, Alice and George.

I have 7 candy bars: Snickers, Hersheys, Milky Way, KitKat, Reeses, Twizzlers and Sour Patch.

Mike likes Snickers, KitKat, Reeses and Twizzlers.

Alice likes KitKat, Hersheys and Sour Patch.

George likes KitKat and Twizzlers.

I want to find out who likes Twizzlers but not Snickers.

This is the code I have so far. With this I get back Mike and George. I only want George. How can I modify the query to give me the results I'm looking for?

```
SELECT Users.firstname, Candy.candyname
FROM Users
INNER JOIN UsersCandy ON Users.id = UsersCandy.user_id
INNER JOIN Candy ON UsersCandy.candy_id = Candy.id
WHERE Candy.candyname = 'Twizzlers'
AND Candy.candyname != 'Snickers'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is testing `candyname` from the same row. If the candy is `Twizzlers`, then it's obviously not also `Snickers`. So your query just finds everyone who likes Twizzlers.

Write a subquery that finds all the users who like Snickers. Then join that with the query that finds users who like Twizzlers. The second join must be a `LEFT JOIN`, so you can test for `NULL` to find a non-matching row, as in [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1).

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.firstname
FROM Users AS u
JOIN UsersCandy AS uc1 ON u.id = uc1.user_id
JOIN Candy AS c1 ON uc1.candy_id = c1.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT u.id
  FROM Users AS u
  JOIN UsersCandy AS uc2 ON u.id = uc2.user_id
  JOIN Candy AS c2 ON uc2.candy_id = c2.id
  WHERE c2.candyname = 'Snickers'
) AS u2
  ON u.id = u2.id
WHERE c1.candyname = 'Twizzlers' AND u2.id IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b741b/20)

Comment: Thank you! I have to figure out how to use this in my project but the logic is very clear.