# How to get missing non numeric IDs in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with ID field format `mm_xxxx` where `xxxx` is an hexadecimal value.

So `mm_1AF8` is a valid ID.

Now I need to get all the singles IDs that are not in use.
I need to search only from `mm_0000` to `mm_FFFF`.

Comment: Create a temporary table that contains all the possible values. Then find all the rows in the temporary table that aren't in the real table.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1 for how to find the rows that don't exist.

Comment: What version of mysql

Comment: @CaiusJard MySQL Version 5.5.29

Answer (score 0):

Combine Barmars response with the answer from Robert McKee

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT z1.*
FROM 
(SELECT CONCAT(@prefix, d1.f,d2.f,d3.f,d4.f) as h
FROM (
  SELECT '0' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '5' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '6' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '7' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '8' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '9' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F' AS f) d1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT '0' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '5' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '6' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '7' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '8' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '9' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F' AS f) d2
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT '0' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '5' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '6' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '7' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '8' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '9' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F' AS f) d3
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT '0' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '5' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '6' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '7' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '8' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT '9' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E' AS f UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F' AS f) d4
) z1,(SELECT @prefix := 'mm_') pre);
```

Comment: I just changed "yourtable" by "Device" and "id" by "deviceID" and the Workbench 6.3 hang up.