# Identify missing conversions with an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, combinations

I need to find a way to find what conversions are missing.

I have three tables.

`Table 1`: `type`, which are the different `types`.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | typeA |
| 2 | typeB |
| 3 | typeC |

`Table 2`: `section`, which are the different `sections`.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | section1 |
| 2 | section2 |
| 3 | section3 |
| 4 | section4 |

`Table 3`: `conversions`, which contains all the combinations to go from one `type` to another for each of the `sections`.

| id | section_id | type_convert_from | type_convert_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 11 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 12 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

For example some are missing from the table above, how can I identify them with a SQL query? Thanks!

Comment: Use a `CROSS JOIN` to create all the possible combinations. Then filter out the combinations that are in the `conversions` table.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1 for how to filter out the matching rows.

Comment: @bonnegnu . . . Some whats are missing?  You have two type columns for instance.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff! Yes, it is to convert from one type to another in each section. Missing conversions need to be identified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The cross join of table `type` with itself generates all possible combinations of type id's. I've excluded combinations in the cross join where `id_from` = `id_to` (ie you're not interested in conversions from a type to itself)

```
select * from conversions C 
    right join (
        select T1.id as id_from, T2.id as id_to 
        from type T1 cross join type T2
        where T1.id <> T2.id
        ) X on X.id_from = C.type_convert_from and X.id_to = C.type_convert_to
    where C.type_convert_from is null
```

If you want to check missing type conversions by section, extend the cross join by adding the `section` table to include `section.id` as follows. It will list missing type conversions within each section.

```
select X.section_id, X.id_from, X.id_to from conversions C 
right join (
    select S.id as section_id, T1.id as id_from, T2.id as id_to 
    from types T1 cross join types T2 cross join section S
     where T1.id <> T2.id
    ) X 
    on X.id_from = C.type_convert_from and X.id_to = C.type_convert_to
    and C.section_id = X.section_id
where C.type_convert_from is null
```

Comment: Hello @John D! Thanks for your help. Yes, I think this is the way. It only remains to add the condition that it checks if the combination exists for each of the sections. How would this be done?

Comment: @bonnegnu I've edited the answer to cater for checking missing conversions within each section.