# Simplified SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently we have to run the following SQL Query to find all customers that have not been assigned access to a downloadable product.

```
SELECT c.entity_id as customer_id, dp.purchased_id as purchased_id
FROM magento_dev.sales_order  as so
JOIN magento_dev.sales_order_address  as soa on so.entity_id = soa.parent_id
JOIN magento_dev.customer_entity as c on c.email = soa.shipping_email
JOIN magento_dev.downloadable_link_purchased as dp on so.increment_id = dp.order_increment_id
where
so.customer_id = 12345 and
so.created_at > '2021-04-01' and
soa.shipping_email is not null and
dp.customer_id != c.entity_id
;
```

Which produces this:

```
customer_id purchased_id
99999   55555
```

Then with the results, we manually have to go through, and for each customer_id, and purchase_id run the following query:

```
UPDATE `magento_dev`.`downloadable_link_purchased` SET `customer_id` = '99999' WHERE (`purchased_id` = '55555');
```

So for the SQL Ninja's, any suggestions on how to make this a single query that finds the mismatched assignments and then does the update/insert at once?

Comment: Are you sure `dp.customer_id != c.entity_id` is the correct condition? That doesn't find customers that haven't been assigned to a product. It joins with every product that was assigned to a different customer.

Comment: Or put another way, it joins with every customer other than the one assigned to to the product.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1 for how to find rows that don't have a matching row in another table.

Comment: Yes, because this is being used for a reseller to buy a product, then assign the downloadable rights to another user. However, the Magento system messes it up, so we have to manually run this and fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put all the JOINs in the UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE `magento_dev`.`downloadable_link_purchased` AS dp1
JOIN magento_dev.sales_order  as so
JOIN magento_dev.sales_order_address  as soa on so.entity_id = soa.parent_id
JOIN magento_dev.customer_entity as c on c.email = soa.shipping_email
JOIN magento_dev.downloadable_link_purchased as dp 
    ON so.increment_id = dp.order_increment_id 
        AND dp.customer_id != c.entity_id 
        AND dp1.purchased_id = dp.purchased_id
SET dp1.customer_id = c.entity_id
where
    so.customer_id = 12345 and
    so.created_at > '2021-04-01' and
    soa.shipping_email is not null
```

Comment: Ok how would that work where the customer_id and purchase_id are variable based on the joins? 

I edited my question above to show what is returned from the first query.

Comment: I didn't realize that the output of the first query was being used as the values to assign and match in the update. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done like sub query and join with the table which should be updated,

```
UPDATE 
    magento_dev.downloadable_link_purchased F
JOIN 
    (SELECT c.entity_id as customer_id, dp.purchased_id as purchased_id
        FROM magento_dev.sales_order  as so
        JOIN magento_dev.sales_order_address  as soa on so.entity_id = soa.parent_id
        JOIN magento_dev.customer_entity as c on c.email = soa.shipping_email
        JOIN magento_dev.downloadable_link_purchased as dp on so.increment_id = dp.order_increment_id
    WHERE
        so.customer_id = 12345 and
        so.created_at > '2021-04-01' and
        soa.shipping_email is not null and
        dp.customer_id != c.entity_id) S
    ON F.purchased_id = S.purchased_id
SET F.customer_id = S.customer_id;
```